# Undulant numbers

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, number-theory

An ***undulant*** number is a number where its digits alternate between *up* and *down* like the following number: 461902 or 708143, or even 1010101, but not 123, because
2 < 3.

Write a program or function which returns a truthy value if a number is *undulant*, and a falsy value otherwise. The shortest code wins.

**Note**: Single digit numbers are a valid input but are not considered *udulant*, thus `isUndulant` returns false for n < 10.

Comment: Number input as string, integer, float...?

Comment: integer (the type function signature Integer -> Boolean)

Comment: What's the objective here? Code-golf (shortest function)?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense for 1-digit numbers. It should be True, False or undefined behavior (preferred) ?

Comment: @JBernardo: I would think True or undefined behavior, as it would be a better base case for recursion.

Comment: @JBernardo: I have added a note for your comment.

Comment: Is the comparison `<`/`>` or `<=`/`>=` ? E.g. is `32213` an undulant number ?

Comment: @Paul: the comparison should be either < or >. so, 32213 is not an undulant because the second and third digits are =.

Comment: Your definition of undulant number is not in agreement with the standard definition: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UndulatingNumber.html.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @mellamokb: I did not know that definition. In fact, I found these numbers in another book which defines the numbers as I did. Also, there are another type of numbers called 'softly undulant' which can be like 12121212 or 1010101010 etc. thanks for your observation.

Comment: My solution could be 16% smaller if the base case were true (as would make sense IMHO).

Comment: How can a question asked almost nine years ago be a duplicate of a question asked today?

Answer (score 6):

**(pdf)eTeX, 129 chars**

```
\def\a#1#2{\if#2?\ifx\r\s\def\s{1}\else
True\end\fi\fi\edef\t{\pdfstrcmp{#2}{#1}}\ifx\s\t
False\end\fi\let\s\t\a#2}\expandafter\a
```

Compiling with `pdfetex filename.tex 1324?` gives a pdf output. TeX is primarily a typesetting language, and outputting instead to stdout would take around 20 more chars. Also the strange requirement for one-digit numbers (false rather than true) takes me 26 chars.

Answer (score 6):

#### Ruby, <strike>72</strike> 70 characters

```
Q=10;k=->n,v{(n%Q-n/Q%Q)*v<0?k[n/Q,-v]:n<Q};u=->n{n>9&&k[n,-1]|k[n,1]}
```

Usage and testcases:

```
p u[10101]   # <= true
p u[708143]  # <= true
p u[2421]    # <= false
p u[1231]    # <= false
p u[873]     # <= false
```

Single digits yield *false*:

```
p u[5]       # <= false
```

Consecutive identical digits also return *false*:

```
p u[66]      # <= false
p u[1221]    # <= false
```

Answer (score 6):

### J, 45

```
*./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=.
```

Sample use:

```
   *./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=. 461902
1
   *./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=. 708143
1
   *./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=. 1010101
1
   *./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=. 123
0
   *./(n>9),(}:(=-)}.)(}:*@-}.)n#:~10$~>.10^.n=. 5
0
```

I'm pretty sure there's a finer way of twisting Insert `/` to do more of the work in a go, but I've been J-less for months, I need to get back to it.

Comment: It will be hard to beat J in this problem. nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

## J, 30 bytes

```
*/0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)2-/\a.i.":
```

A different approach than the other J answers.

```
   */0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)2-/\a.i.":461902
1
   */0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)2-/\a.i.":708143
1
   */0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)2-/\a.i.":1010101
1
   */0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)2-/\a.i.":123
0
   */0<(#,]*{.*1 _1$~#)(}.-}:)a.i.":5
0
```

Would be 3 characters shorter if 5 were considered undulant.

Comment: Well, at least I can console myself with the thought that I had the lead for an hour. :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <strike>88</strike> <strike>77</strike> <strike>73</strike> 65 characters

```
z=tail>>=zipWith compare
q[]=0>1
q s=all(/=EQ)$s++z s
u=q.z.show
```

This requires the commonly used language pragma (or `-X` flag): `NoMonomorphismRestriction`. If you don't admit that, we have to add 4 characters and define `z` thus:

```
z s=zipWith compare s$tail s
```

Comment: I am so furious that you beat my 104 char solution. `u n=length s>1&&(a[GT,LT]||a[LT,GT])where s=show n;z=q compare s$tail s;w=q(==)z;q=zipWith;a=and.w.cycle` It's kinda elegant. `zipWith` once with `compare` like you did, then `zipWith` again with `(==)` and `cycle[GT,LT]` or `cycle[LT,GT]` as second arg.

Comment: you could inline w as `tail>>=zipWith compare` which would shorten few bytes.

Comment: also, I golfed a shorter version of `q`: `q[]=0<1;q(a:b:s)|a/=b,a/=EQ=q$b:s;q _=0>1`

Comment: actually, here's an even shorter version:                   `q s=and$all(/=EQ)s:zipWith(/=)s(tail s)`

Comment: @proudhaskeller - neither version passes all tests. They both fail on 3 (should be False), and the first fails many others, like 32 and 101010101.

Comment: @proudhaskeller - Your second idea was easy to fix, but the fix brought it back to 88 characters... However it then let me factor out `zipWith f s$tail s` saving 11 characters!

Comment: You could shorten it by one using `(%)f=tail>>=zipWith f`

Comment: Actually you would get a lower score making `%` not an operator

Comment: @proudhaskeller - done!

Answer (score 4):

## Sage, <strike>83</strike> 76 bytes

```
f=lambda x:uniq(cmp(*`x`[i-2:i][::(-1)^i])for i in[2..len(`x`)])in[[1],[-1]]
```

Got the idea to use cmp(*[..]) from JBernardo.  In Sage, `uniq(...)` is an alias for `list(set(...))`.

Edit: just noticed that for x < 10, `uniq(cmp(...)) == []`, which isn't on `[[1],[-1]]`.  If x were input as a string, instead of an integer, I could get another 4 characters out!

Comment: I had an idea to use `sum(uniq(...))^2`, since `sum([1,-1]) = 0`, and the sums of the singletons [1] and [-1] squares to 1.  Unfortunately, it fails on a thrice-repeated digit; 1011101.

Comment: Nice. I should learn sage.
BTW, I just realized that backticks will append an `L` if the number is bigger than 2**32 in Python and affects the result. Does that happens on Sage?

Comment: Yeah, Sage makes a few things nice for golfing... for instance, its ridiculous startup time is spent importing a huge tree of modules.  The Sage Integer class doesn't bother with the `L` because Sage is preparsed python; 1234 -> Integer('1234').  You can jump right into using Sage here: http://sagenb.org

Answer (score 4):

#### Python: <s>101</s> 100 characters

Before minification:

```python
undulate = (lambda n: n > 9
            and all(cmp(*digits) == (i % 2) * 2 - 1
                    for i, digits
                    in enumerate(zip(min(`n`,`n`[1:]), 
                                     max(`n`,`n`[1:])))))
```

After minification:

```
a=lambda b:b>9and all(cmp(*c)==d%2*2-1 for d,c in enumerate(zip(min(`b`,`b`[1:]),max(`b`,`b`[1:]))))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <s>134</s> 129 chars

```
def f(x):d=[cmp(*i)for i in zip(`x`,`x`[1:])]if x>9 else[0];n=d[0]>0;return all(i<0 for i in d[n::2])&all(i>0 for i in d[n<1::2])
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(x):
    if x>9:
        d = [cmp(*i)for i in zip(`x`,`x`[1:])] #difference of x[i] and x[i+1]
    else:
        d = [0]       #trick to return False if x<10 using less chars
    n = d[0]>0        #First digit is -1 or 1?
    neg = d[n::2]     #negative numbers if x is Undulant
    pos = d[not n::2] #positive numbers if x is Undulant

    #check if all negs are -1 and all pos are 1 and return value
    return all(i<0 for i in neg) and all(i>0 for i in pos)
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 88 chars

```js
function _(i){i+='';c=i[0];f=i[a=x=1];for(g=f<c;d=i[x++];c=d)g^=a&=g?d<c:d>c;return!f^a}
```

In essence, turn the number into a string and compare adjacent characters, flipping the expectation for each.

Comment: In JavaScript, a function doesn't need a name and the question asks explicitly for a function, so you can save two characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>119</s> 108 bytes

```python
def u(x):l=[cmp(i,j)for i,j in zip(`x`,`x`[1:])];print x>9and all([i*j<0 for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])])and l!=[0]
```

Comment: Nice use of xor.  You can cut quite a few characters out with `... for a,b in zip(t,t[1:])` rather than using ranges.  Also, you don't need the brackets in `all([...])` -- Python makes a generator when it finds `(... for ...)`, even if the parentheses are for a function call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! They have been very valuable! -20 chars

Comment: Very nice solution. Few more characters `x>9 and all(i^j for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]))` and remove `if l else False`.

Comment: It is not working in all cases. Two cases are problematic: only 2 digits (e.g. 11), and last 2 digits are same and larger than one before (e.g. 12155). First problem is since there is no testing if x<100. Second is because 'one way comparison'. It can be fix with `cmp(i,j)` and instead `i^j` set `i*j<0`, and testing `and l[0]!=0`.
Few more characters :-/

Comment: Thank you! +9 chars, but now all working.

Comment: Hmmm... `print` saves one character over `return`, but is it legitimate? The spec does ask for a function that "returns".

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 82 bytes

```
c=cycle[(<),(>)]
l!n=n>9&&and(zipWith3($)l(show n)$tail$show n)
u n=c!n||((>):c)!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9k2uTI5JzVaw0ZTR8NOM5YrRzHPNs/OUk0tMS9FoyqzIDyzJMNYQ0UzR6M4I79cIU9TpSQxM0cFyuEqVcizTVbMq6nRAOq2StZUzPufm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKJQqmBiZmhpYPQfAA)

Comment: I count only 83 characters in this solution. (Are you on Windows, perhaps? Write the file with unix line endings, which is legal Haskell.)

Comment: Thanks, I was using 'wc' to count my characters on Cygwin. I count 82 characters. I used the following code, as wc seems to be outputting an extra character. (Vim doesn't show a trailing newline, but notepad does...)

`readFile "Undulant.hs" >>= print . length . dropWhile (== '\n') . reverse . filter (/= '\r')`

Comment: `c=cycle[(<),(>)]` can be shortened to `c=(<):(>):c`.

Comment: `zipWith3($)l(show n)$tail$show n` can be `zipWith3($)l=<<tail$show n` and `((>):c)` can be `tail c`. All together 70 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoMwEADAu69YIYTkVmspRLJ@w3NIhSxdV6kRQfx7qrdhUli/I3MpEY23neltFyuuBaV3Wgf5mIOWgXJqjbKM3udArNY07yC22kAw1nKe98KlMgUSQFh@JBkUbPB6N@7xLH8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## J, <strike>44</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>36</strike> 31 bytes

```
*/2(0<#@],0>*/\)*2-/\".;' ',.":
```

Usage as before.

I hadn't noticed that my last edit made the inequality with 0 check completely unnecessary. :-)

Previous answer (+ explanation):

```
(0=+/2=/\u)*(1<#u)**/2~:/\2<:/\u=.".;' ',.":
```

Usage:

```
    (0=+/2=/\u)*(1<#u)**/2~:/\2<:/\u=.".;' ',.":461902
1
```

The answer has four parts:

1. `u=.".;' ',.":`
   This reads in the number as a string `":`, splits it into a list of characters preceded by spaces `' ',.`, stitches it back together `;`, converts it back to numbers `".` and then stores the result `u=.` This basically turns 461902 into 4 6 1 9 0 2 which I find easier to process in J.
2. `*/2~:/\2<:/\`
   This operates on the value stored in u. It takes each pair of characters and checks if the left one is less than or equal to the right one `2<:/\` so 4 6 1 9 0 2 becomes 1 0 1 0 1. It then takes the result of this and checks each pair of numbers for inequality `2~:/\` so 1 0 1 0 1 becomes 1 1 1 1. Finally it multiplies them all together to get either a 0 or a 1 `*/` At this point we could return the answer if it weren't for 2 things: a single digit returns 1 when the question requires a 0; and equal numbers are treated the same as 'less than' so 461900 returns 1 instead of 0. Bummer. On we go...
3. `(1<#u)`
   This checks if the number of items stored in u `#u` is greater than 1 and returns false if it's just a single digit number.
4. `(0=+/2=/\u)`
   This takes each pair of numbers stored in u and checks for equality `2=/\u`. It then sums the answers and checks if it has 0.

The results of parts 2, 3 and 4 are then multiplied together to (hopefully) produce a 1 when the number meets the requirements specified in the question.

Comment: Nice job re-taking the lead, but I just borrowed a trick from yours!

Comment: (That being said, I think you could take my `a.i.":` to shave a few more characters off.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm probably going to have to put that inequality check back in - my answer fails now for 11, 22, 33, 44 etc.

Answer (score 3):

## CoffeeScript, <del>98</del> <del>67</del> 53 bytes

```
(n)->0!in((n[i]>=c^(n[0]<n[1])+i)%2for c,i in n[1..])
```

Tests:

```
[
    '01010101' # true
    '12345'    # false
    '1010101'  # true
    '887685'   # false
    '9120734'  # true
    '090909'   # true
]
```

Uncompressed:

```
undulant = (n) ->
    direction = n[0] < n[1]
    return n.split('').every (cur, i) ->
        prev = arr[i-1] or 10 * direction
        +(prev >= cur) is (direction+i)%2
```

Answer (score 3):

## K, 41 bytes

```
{(x>9)&~max(=). 1_'-':'1_'(<':;>':)@\:$x}
```

E.g.

```
{(x>9)&~max(=). 1_'-':'1_'(<':;>':)@\:$x}1212130659
1b
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 155 chars

```
g=lambda a,b:all(x>y for x,y in zip(a,b))
u=lambda D:g(D[::2],D[1::2])&g(D[2::2],D[1::2])
def U(n):D=map(int,str(n));return(n>9)&(u(D)|u([-d for d in D]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 94 chars

```
bool u(int N){int K,P,Q,U=1,D=1;while(N>9)P=N%10,Q=(N/=10)%10,K=D,D=U&Q<P,U=K&Q>P;return U^D;}
```

same method as my Erlang awnser with a for loop rather than recursion.

Answer (score 2):

### Python <s>105</s> <s>101</s> 100 chars

```
c=lambda r,t:len(r)<2 or(cmp(*r[:2])==t and c(r[1:],-t))
u=lambda x:x>9and c(`x`,cmp(*`x`[:2])or 1)
```

Recursive solution. `c(r,t)` checks if first char of `r` is less `(t==-1)` or greater `(t==1)` of second char, and call opposite check on shortened string.

Comment: Nice. You can save a character in the first line by removing `0`, and you can save three characters on the second line by writing `u=lambda x:x>9 and c(\`x\`,cmp(*\`x\`[:2])or 1)`

Comment: Tnx. I didn't like any() from the beginning :-)

Comment: You can save one more by writing `x>9and`.

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 48 bytes

```
[`..,(<\1>]zip{..$=\-1%.$=-}%(\{.@*0<*}/abs
```

Hoping to beat J, my first time using GolfScript.  Didn't quite succeed.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl/re, 139 bytes

Doing **everything** in regex is kind of a bad idea.

```
/^(?:(.)(?{local$a=$1}))?(?:(?>((.)(?(?{$a lt$3})(?{local$a=$3})|(?!)))((.)(?(?{$a gt$5})(?{local$a=$5})|(?!))))*(?2)?)(?(?{pos>1})|(?!))$/
```

I'm using Perl 5.12 but I think this will work on Perl 5.10.  Pretty sure 5.8 is out though.

```
for (qw(461902 708143 1010101 123 5)) {
    print "$_ is " . (/crazy regex goes here/ ? '' : 'not ') . "undulant\n";
}

461902 is undulant
708143 is undulant
1010101 is undulant
123 is not undulant
5 is not undulant
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

Takes input as a string, returns `true` for undulant numbers, an empty string (falsey) for single digit numbers and `false` otherwise.

```js
([s,...a])=>a+a&&a.every(x=>eval(s+"<>"[++y%2]+x,s=x),y=s<a)
```

---

### Try it

Run the Snippet below to test `0-9` and 25 random numbers `<10,000,000`.

```js
f=
([s,...a])=>a+a&&a.every(x=>eval(s+"<>"[++y%2]+x,s=x),y=s<a)
tests=new Set([...Array(10).keys()])
while(tests.add(Math.random()*1e7|0).size<35);
o.innerText=[...tests].map(x=>(x=x+``).padStart(7)+` = `+JSON.stringify(f(x))).join`\n`
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

---

### Explanation

A few fun little tricks in this one so I think it warrants a rare explanation to a JS solution from me.

```
()=>
```

We start, simply, with an anonymous function which takes the integer string as an argument when called.

```
[s,...a]
```

That argument is immediately destructured into 2 parameters: `s` being the first character in the string and `a` being an array containing the remaining characters (e.g. `"461902"` becomes `s="4"` and `a=["6","1","9","0","2"]`).

```
a+a&&
```

First, we concatenate `a` with itself, which casts both occurrences to strings. If the input is a single digit number then `a` will be empty and, therefore, become and empty string; an empty string plus an empty string is still an empty string and, because that's falsey in JS, we stop processing at the logical AND and output our empty string. In all other cases `a+a` will be truthy and so we continue on to the next part of the function.

```
a.every(x=>)
```

We'll be checking if every element `x` in `a` returns `true` when passed through a function.

```
y=s<a
```

This determines what our first comparison will be (`<` or `>`) and then we'll alternate from there. We check if the string `s` is less than the array `a`, which gets cast to a string in the process so, if `s` is less than the first character in `a`, `y` will be `true` or `false` if it's not.

```
s+"<>"[++y%2]+x
```

We build a string with the current value of `s` at the beginning and `x` at the end. In between, we index into the string `"<>"` by incrementing `y`, casting its initial boolean value to an integer, and modulo by 2, giving us `0` or `1`.

```
eval()
```

Eval that string.

```
s=x
```

Finally, we pass a second argument to `eval`, which it ignores, and use it to set the value of `s` to the current value of `x` for the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang, <strike>137</strike> <strike>123</strike> 118 chars

```
u(N)->Q=N div 10,u(Q,N rem 10,Q>0,Q>0). u(0,_,D,U)->D or U;u(N,P,D,U)->Q=N rem 10,u(N div 10,Q,U and(Q<P),D and(Q>P)).
```

Comment: Won't this return True so long as there has been at least one up and one down transition anywhere? Won't it return True for, say 1234321?

Comment: @ MtnViewMark, yeah it did thanks, I misunderstood the question fixed now hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, <strike>141 133 129</strike> 97 bytes

```
def u(n:Int):Boolean=n>9&&{
val a=n%10
val b=(n/10)%10
a!=b&&n<99||(a-b*b-(n/100)%10)<0&&u(n/10)}
```

With a = n % 10, b = (n/10) % 10, c = (n/100) % 10

```
if a > b and b < c or 
   a < b and b > c
```

Then `a-b * b-c` is either `x*-y` or `-x*y` with `x` and `y` as positive numbers, and the product is in both cases negative, but for `-x*-y` or `x*y` (a < b < c or a > b > c) the product is always positive.

The rest of the code is handling special cases: one digit, two digits, two identical digits.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 88

Naïve and trivial. I will golf later.

```
filter u{-join([char[]]"$_"|%{if($n){[Math]::Sign($n-$_)+1}$n=$_})-notmatch'1|22|00|^$'}
```

[My test cases](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/CG3134/test.ps1).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 112

```
function(n,d,l,c,f){while(l=n%10,n=n/10|0)d=n%10,c?c>0?d>=l?(f=0):(c=-c):d<=l?(f=0):(c=-c):(c=d-l,f=1);return f}
```

You only need to pass it one argument. I could probably golf this further with a for loop.

Comment: (`d>=l` -> `d>0`) and (`d<=l` -> `d<2`) perhaps? I'm not looking closely, as perhaps `d` might contain fractional parts that might skew it.

Comment: @trinithis: That's a lowercase `L`, not a `1`. Thanks though!

Comment: Where's DejaVu Sans Mono or Bitstream Vera Sans Mono when you need it? Perhaps I need to customize stackoverflow with some custom css or a user script...

Comment: @trinithis: I agree, the font choice isn't that great. Bolding doesn't stand out enough...

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 71 bytes

```
{$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]}
```

Sample usage:

```
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 5
0b
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 10101
1b
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 01010
1b
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 134679
0b
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 123456
0b
q){$[x>9;any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':){"I"$x}each -3!x;0b]} 132436
1b
```

Comment: You can logic away the if `{(x>9)&any all a=#[;(1 -1;-1 1)](#)a:1_signum(-':)("I"$')($)x}` gives 62

Comment: Never seen `($)` syntax for `string` before and the logic is a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 78 bytes

```
sub u{@_=split//,$_=shift;s/.(?=.)/($&cmp$_[$+[0]])+1/ge;chop;$#_&&!/00|1|22/}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
#!=Sort@#&&#!=Reverse@Sort@#&[IntegerDigits@n]
```

Examples (spaces are not required):

```
# != Sort@# && # != Reverse@Sort@# &[IntegerDigits@5]
# != Sort@# && # != Reverse@Sort@# &[IntegerDigits@123]
# != Sort@# && # != Reverse@Sort@# &[IntegerDigits@132]
# != Sort@# && # != Reverse@Sort@# &[IntegerDigits@321]

(*  out *)
False  False  True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 30 bytes

CJam is newer than this challenge, so this does not compete for the green checkmark, but it's not a winner anyway (although I'm sure this can actually be golfed quite a bit).

```
l"_1=\+{_@-\}*;]"_8'*t+~{W>},!
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

### How it works

Firstly, I'm doing some string manipulation (followed by eval) to save 5 bytes on duplicate code:

```
"..."_8'*t+~
"..."        "Push this string.":
     _       "Duplicate.";
      8'*t   "Replace the 8th character (the -) with *.";
          +~ "Concatenate the strings and evaluate.";
```

So in effect my code is

```
l_1=\+{_@-\}*;]_1=\+{_@*\}*;]{W>},!
```

First, here is how I deal with the weird special case of a single digit. I copy the digit at index `1` and prepend it to the number. We need to distinguish 3 cases:

- The first two digits are different, like `12...`, then we get `212...`, so the start is undulant, and won't affect whether the entire number is undulant.
- The first two digits are the same, like `11...`, then we get `111...`. Now the start is not undulant, but the number wasn't undulant anyway, so this won't affect the result either.
- If the number only has one digit, the digit at index `1` will be the first digit (because CJam's array indexing loops around the end), so this results in two identical digits, and the number is *not* undulant.

Now looking at the code in detail:

```
l_1=\+{_@-\}*;]_1=\+{_@*\}*;]{W>},!
l                                   "Read input.";
 _1=\+                              "Prepend second digit.";
      {_@-\}*                       "This fold gets the differences of consecutive elments.";
             ;]                     "Drop the final element and collect in an aray.";
               _1=\+                "Prepend second element.";
                    {_@*\}*         "This fold gets the products of consecutive elments.";
                           ;]       "Drop the final element and collect in an aray.";
                             {W>},  "Filter out non-negative numbers.";
                                  ! "Logical not.";
```

I'm sure there is a shorter way to actually check digits (of length greater 1) for whether they are undulant (in particular, without using two folds), but I couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

#### Prolog 87 bytes

```
u(X) :- number_codes(X,C),f(C).
f([_,_]).
f([A,B,C|L]) :- (A<B,B>C;A>B,B<C),f([B,C|L]).
```

To run it, just save it as golf.pl, open a prolog interpreter (e.g. gprolog) in the same directory then do:

```
consult(golf).
u(101010).
```

It will give `true` if the number is undulant, otherwise just no.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 62 bytes

```julia
f(x,a=sign.(diff(digits(x))))=x>9&&-a*a[1]==(-1).^(1:endof(a))
```

Takes in a number, returns `true` for Undulant, and `false` for not. Eg `f(163)` returns `true`.

```julia
f(x,a=sign.(diff(digits(x))))=x>9&&-a*a[1]==(-1).^(1:endof(a))
f(x,                        )                                   # function definition
    a=sign.(diff(digits(x)))                                    # default 2nd argument is array of differences of signs of digits
                              x>9&&                             # short circuiting and to catch cases under 10
                                   -a*a[1]                      # make the first element of a always -1
                                          ==(-1).^(1:endof(a))  # check that a is an array of alternating -1 and 1 of correct length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETv/YrYQ9mILaSRgEJE/AZvohBtElIkHjaF/H1cESHuwDCP2cPMyzMYVYqDvDEag48DTME5Mh8SQuZ0Oh92XdebtbmIq9bQCz7cQOxtnF4ODOdlwRA9Oxm0w9liao6JHG1i7SewBxXYsrv1IX47tnIgeJWl@hGBkn@wrR@VrMuRJIUcSbyhPeUN)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>91</s> <s>94</s> 86 bytes

Takes input from stdin, outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` as appropriate.

```r
all(-(z=sign(diff((x=scan())%/%10^(1:nchar(x)-1)%%10)))*z[1]==(-1)^(1:(l=sum(1|z))))&l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrhCkAwFIbhq5m@o2QnitS5ElGLhpr9sJSWe5/5@7zvlZJxDhWihGPzWA9rgUfCYjyIVK1Yz@DBL7u58FDFpDIRURlHnkSQ5R/gJNwn@I25UeFSp3tum/QB)

This uses basically the same algorithm as gggg's [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154597/59052), but it's a little more verbose.

Added 3 bytes as the first version didn't account for numbers of length `1` always being nonundulant ("unundulant"?). Removed 8 bytes thanks to some golfing of redundant parts.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 151 chars

```
function i($n){$n=str_split($n);@$p=$n[1]==null?:($m=($n[0]>=$n[1])?-1:1)*10;foreach($n as$k=>$v)if(($k%2*2-1)*($v-$p)*@$m<=0&$p=$v)return!1;return!0;}
```

ungolfed(-ish):

```
function is_undulant($n){

      $n=str_split($n);
      @$p=$n[1]==null?:($m = ($n[0] >= $n[1])? -1 : 1)*10;
      foreach ($n as$k=>$v)
        if ( ($k%2 * 2 - 1) * ($v - $p) * @$m <= 0 & $p=$v ) return !1;

      return !0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 124 bytes

```python
def undulant(x):
    x = `x`
    return any((int(x[1])-int(x[0]))*-1**i*(int(x[i])-int(x[i-1]))>0 for i in range(2,len(x)))
```

Different approach I think.

Comment: You should tell us what language that is.

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 194 characters

```
def u(i:Int):Boolean={val x=i.toString;if(!x.matches("(\\d)\\1")){"(?<=.*)(\\d)(?=(\\d).*)".r.replaceAllIn(x,m=>if(m.group(1)<m.group(2))"<"else">").matches("((<>)+<?)|((><)+>?)\\d")}else false}
```

Hmm...regex seemed like a good idea at the time...

Comment: [Doing **everything** in regex is kind of a bad idea.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5257/2909)  (Your comment inspired me!)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>147</s> 142 bytes

```
bool U(int i){if(i<10)return 0>1;var s=i+"";var b=s[0]>s[1];for(int j=2;j<s.Length;j++){var x=s[j-1]>s[j];if(x==b)return 0>1;b=x;}return 1>0;}
```

Working sample: http://ideone.com/b8ubr

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>79</s> <s>77</s> 69 bytes

```
a=raw_input()
print{cmp(a[i+1],a[i])for i in range(len(a)-1)}=={-1,1}
```

Comment: Incorrect.  Try 1221.

Comment: No, 1221 works. It returns True.

Comment: It should return false.

Comment: Fixed it. Now it's one single formula. :)

Comment: 12321 should return False.

Comment: Why? There are no equal adjacent numbers, and it goes up and down.

Comment: It goes (up, up, down, down).  It should go (up, down, up, down) or (down, up, down, up).  Also, the task is to provide a function.

Comment: If your answer were correct, it could be shortened by using this technique:  `f=lambda a:{cmp(*x)for x in zip(a,a[1:])}=={-1,1}`

Answer (score 0):

## APL (Dyalog), <s>43</s> 21 bytes

ASCII is way too limited! :P

```
{⍵≤9:0⋄∧/2≠/×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

In standard APL fashion, it returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

Usage:

```
  {⍵≤9:0⋄∧/2≠/×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}461902
1
  {⍵≤9:0⋄∧/2≠/×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}708143
1
  {⍵≤9:0⋄∧/2≠/×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}123
0
  {⍵≤9:0⋄∧/2≠/×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}6
0
```

Explanation:

- `⍵≤9:0⋄`: If the argument is smaller or equal to `9`, it's not an undulant number. Otherwise...
- `⍎¨⍕⍵`: evaluate each character in the string representation of `⍵` (giving a list of digits)
- `2-/`: subtract each pair of consecutive digits from each other (i.e. `(4-6),(6-1),(1-9),(9-0),(0-2)`)
- `×`: find the sign of each number in that list
- `2≠/`: for each pair of consecutive signs, see if they are not equal
- `∧/`: check if this is true for all pairs

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 89 chars

```
def f(a):z=[cmp(*x)for x in zip(a[1:],a)];return{(a&b)-(a^b)for a,b in zip(z[1:],z)}=={3}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (Clang), 78 bytes

```
u(i){int d,p=0;while(i>9){d=i%10-(i/=10)%10;if(d*p>0|!d)i=d=0;p=d;}return!!p;}
```

Expanded code with test harness:

```
u(i){
  int d,p=0;
    while(i>9) {
      d=i%10-(i/=10)%10;
      if(d*p>0|!d)i=d=0;
      p=d;
  }
  return !!p;
}

void test(int i) {
  printf("%8d = %d\n", i, u(i));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  test(132);
  test(123);
  test(5);
  test(1332);
  test(176823);
}
```

(compiled with Apple clang version 3.1)

Results:

```
     132 = 1
     123 = 0
       5 = 0
    1332 = 0
  176823 = 1
```

Comment: Apparently `u(132)` is `0`. Am I doing something wrong? http://ideone.com/MMrfM

Comment: while I spotted an error in my first version, it was still returning 1 for u(132) for me - odd.

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 19 characters

```
{a≡⍳⍴a←|-\×2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```