# Is that number a Two Bit Number™?

Tags: code-golf, math, binary

Let's start by defining a Two Bit Number™:

- It is a positive integer
- When expressed as a binary string it has exactly 2 true bits OR
- When expressed as a decimal number, it has exactly 2 of the numeral one, and all other numerals are zero.

Or as a sentence

A Two Bit Number™ is a number which contains exactly 2 of the numeral 1 and no other numerals besides 0, when expressed as a decimal string or a binary number.

So here area all the Two Bit Numbers™ between 0 and 256

```
Dec  Bin       Type
3    00000011  Binary
5    00000101  Binary
6    00000110  Binary
9    00001001  Binary
10   00001010  Binary
11   00001011  Decimal
12   00001100  Binary
17   00010001  Binary
18   00010010  Binary
20   00010100  Binary
24   00011000  Binary
33   00100001  Binary
34   00100010  Binary
36   00100100  Binary
40   00101000  Binary
48   00110000  Binary
65   01000001  Binary
66   01000010  Binary
68   01000100  Binary
72   01001000  Binary
80   01010000  Binary
96   01100000  Binary
101  01100101  Decimal
110  01101110  Decimal
129  10000001  Binary
130  10000010  Binary
132  10000100  Binary
136  10001000  Binary
144  10010000  Binary
160  10100000  Binary
192  11000000  Binary
```

The challenge:

- Write some code which accepts a number and outputs true or false (or some indicator of true or false) if it is a Two Bit Number™.
- Input will always be an integer, but it may not always be positive.
- It can be in any language you like.
- It's code golf, so the fewest bytes wins.
- Please include links to an online interpreter for your code (such as tio.run).

### Test Cases

Binary Two Bit Numbers™:

```
3
9 
18 
192
288
520
524304
```

Decimal Two Bit Numbers™:

```
11
101
1001
1010
1100
1000001
1100000000
1000000010
```

Non Two Bit Numbers™:

```
0
1
112 (any numerals over 1 prevent it being a Decimal Two Bit Number™)
200
649
-1
-3
```

---

Fun fact: I was not able to find any DecimalBinary Two Bit Numbers™ checking up to about 14 billion, and I have a hypothesis that such a number does not exist, but I have no mathematical proof. I'd be interested to hear if you can think of one.

Comment: I've sketched out a somewhat clumsy [proof that no DB2B number exists](https://tio.run/##dVJLboMwEN37FK@bCoyi4krtIqq5y6A4aiRIKujHnKQH6sHojI0DKZQF83nzfeM31zXP4ziaUmuPAiIHWDxqTWyyqNWACh73qFmSUo1rW9rjcjjg5zsIK3@F@LlPd54Bsf4iQa4hrct1Ja1TKL5eXedwrsqEc2iEFzmmmKqLT1Hff7SOh7eQLPPPgoiWhZGgOUCQIzW9Ux53UqI/taeGumYARYeKvPFSmSlEz4adz3Mb6kUvq1m9ozy/jkOV9Vz5aSszNs6I9VU@bjlfxkUGrp5Eiezk574vqW@YLTT1XHk9/nbbm4Tl3ac273Kg44WPNDk2HpVPnIftI8sPAVcqUD3@Ag). Not sure if it makes sense though

Comment: @JoKing I'm not completely sure I follow it, but as far as I can tell that's correct. My script has just reached 11 billion with no results.

Comment: @JoKing How do you get from `10^x+10^y = 2^x+2^b` to `5^x = 2^b/10^y`? It looks like you may have incorrectly treated the former expression as though it said `*` instead of `+`, and then divided both sides by `2^x*10^y`.

Comment: I hoped to find some power of ten `10^k` so that `2^a+2^b mod 10^k ≠ 0` (which takes a finite amount of work to check); this would eliminate much of the possibility of finding a DB2B number. But I fear there's no such `k`. (Fun fact: `2^7 + 2^31257` ends in seven zeroes.)

Comment: `Input will always be an integer, but it may not always be positive.` How are negative numbers encoded? With a minus in front? With a 1 in front? Using two's complement?

Comment: @Stef I would assume however the language you are using handles negative integers. I'd just add a minus at the beginning.

Comment: I checked for DecimalBinary Two Bit Numbers™️ up to 10^100000 using an optimized method, and didn't find any.

Comment: @xnor you’ve just made my day by including the ™️. I’ve got a naive method running over night, but I’m pretty darned confident we’re not going to find any.

Comment: The existence of DecimalBinary Two Bit Numbers™️ is a fascinating nerd-snipe problem!

Comment: You have -1 as not a Two Bit number (it would be in 2-s complement), you have -3 as not a Two Bit number (it would be with a minus sign character prepended). You do not have `-11` as an example (again would be with a minus sign). I can only imagine that your rule is to convert to a base representation using digits in \$[-b+1..0]\$ e.g. -123 base 10 is `[-1,-2,-3]` \$= -1 \times 10^2 + -2 \times 10^1 + -1 \times 10^0\$. Without a spec it seems we can say all negative numbers are not Two Bit Numbers, so why, are there example ones and why do we even need to handle them?

Comment: I'd suggest 2-adic analysis techniques to determine when `5^x(10^y+1)` can be `2^b+1`.

Comment: Can we even rule out that `5^x * 11 = 2^b + 1`?

Comment: @xnor It seems like these two expressions are never equal modulo 20.

Comment: @thedefault Nice find, it looks like even mod 4, `5^x * 11`  is 3 and `2^b + 1` is 1 for `b>=2`. This makes me wonder if we can find a similar modulo obstruction for `101, 1001, ...`, or in general.

Comment: `5^x(10^y+1) == 2^b+1` is always false modulo 1025 when `x`, `y` or `b` are >= 1025. I tested with values of `x`, `y` and `b` below 1200, and found no solutions. I suspect that this proves that no DecimalBinary Two Bit Numbers™️ exist.

Comment: Fascinating discussion here, although it feels a bit of a chunky comment chain. Here's a chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113602/decimalbinary-two-bit-numbers-

Comment: Can you please explain what is a DecimalBinary number? Probably a number which is a valid decimal and binary (i.e, comprised only of '0's and '1's)?

Comment: No, that does not make sense, as any Decimal TBN is also a valid binary. So, maybe a Decimal TBN, whose binary representation is a TBN as well?

Comment: @ysap I think you’ve got it. It’s a positive integer which is a Two Bit Number™️ when expressed either as a decimal number or a binary number.

Comment: It's at the end of the chat log, but it's worth linking here too. [There is a complete proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846781/is-there-a-solution-to-2a2b-10c10d-with-0-leq-a-b-and-0-leq-c/3846870#3846870) of the nonexistence of DecimalBinary Two Bit Numbers™.

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>68</s> <s>62</s> 48 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!
-14 bytes thanks to [Jitse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87681/jitse)!

```python
lambda n:' 11 'in f' {n:b} {n} '.replace('0','')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoJADETvfMXcCslidgENkOiPIAdUVklwIYgHQ/h2bCHGQyftm2na/jM@Ohcv9nhe2up5uVVwOcEYUONgCZPLLzPrDNoNdd9W19onTYooWMb6Nb5wROEBRayQKZiUK4sUopS7faRFklgnpZKQMWzrVTY1HDA8rERvcOv0HzLW274gScgB8Q8J3wwZhTEHSs@z3YD70L178PvrfznvCZVB4OoKBPqhcaNvaRJvRnjCZH3pg5kC7@cHyxc)

Comment: @user your 51 bytes returns `false` for all valid binaries entries

Comment: Its looks like you can cut the `(n>0)*` because any negative values will fail the test due to their minus sign.

Comment: you can replace `s.replace('0','')=='11'` with `s.count('1')==2`

Comment: @Turksarama this would fail for inputs like `121`. The `s.replace('0','')=='11'` makes sure there are no other digits.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY/BCoMwDIbvPkVusVClVTdUcC/iPOimm@Bq0e4wxGd3iTJ26E/y/X9IYz/uOZp464rrNtSv5l6DyVFr7A10uJi8WWExK4ZTa4f61vqoUCKKcLZD73yxuXZ2MxRQegBlLCGToFN6WSQhSqk6RYoliVVSSQ5pTbba5VBNAU3NTtQBj0r9IWF1zDPiBC9g/5zQzoBQEFOg8rxunOAxjW8LdMT@v5zmmHLDcHcZAtipN86nU9lbIbjA0vlcixWF9/PF9gU "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jitse Nice one! I was able to get 4 bytes more off by adding some spaces ;)

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
f n=or[b^x+b^y==n|b<-[2,10],x<-[0..n],y<-[x+1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBDoMgEEbhq8yiO38Mo5s2kZMQTCSRlJSODXWBiXdHXL1v897L/7OmVGsgMVu2fi6dnw9j5PSTsgNYO5Qm3fficDSVjm@7@l2ikKFfjrLTg0JM@5opkB3xAj/B3G6GRisPUAw1unoB)

Brute force search.

### Alternative 50 bytes

```hs
b!0=0
b!x=rem x b^3+b!quot x b
f n=2!n==2||10!n==2
```

`b!x` computes a base-`b` “cubed digit sum” of `x`. For example, `10!123` = \$1^3+2^3+3^3\$ = 36.

We check if either of `2!n` or `10!n` equals 2.

`quot` is necessary to support negative input. It rounds toward zero, whereas `div` rounds down, meaning `div (-1) 10 == (-1)`, causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Returns **0** for *true*, or a non-zero integer for *false*.

```javascript
n=>(g=n=>!(n&=n-1)|n&n-1)(n)*g('0b'+n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHLDoIwEEX3fgVuaKtBW0ADMbj0C9ypi8pLDA4G0ITEf8caFj5m3LTJ6Z07tzNnfddNXBfX1oEqSfss6iFa8zwy55iDHYGjxAPs18VBTHLO5JFNQfRxBU1VprOyMmy3rW/tqbPm1rEAXXcHJlajT0XGPSF@SIiICjAKXcTcAOsWriSY70nf4C/O9vCOm6RxcdElkVcpnEVSjIQKp1FGSpVL0mF4kH9L5NAC/Wyjy4YaP@FDNCVmTSRY@nh1DrZzzMr7Jw)

#### How?

The helper function **g** removes the two least significant bits set in `n` by computing `n & (n - 1)` twice. If we get **0** the first time, it means that `n` has at most one bit set, which is not enough. If we *don't* get **0** the second time, it means that `n` has more than 2 bits set, which is too much.

For the decimal test, we invoke **g** with `'0b' + n` to parse it as a binary value. If `n` is negative, this gives something such as `'0b-10100'`, which is NaN'ish and fails as expected.

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>40</s>  39 bytes

Returns a Boolean value telling whether the input is *not* a Two Bit Number.

```javascript
n=>[n,'0b'+n].every(n=>!(n&=n-1)|n&n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNDoJADIX3ngI3DETBGUADMbj0BO6QxQCDYrAYQBIS744YFv60rib55vX1tb3ITjZpXdxaC6pMDXk4QLiLYMl4whYQ26pTdW@MbG6AHoIlzAfor2dIK2iqUtlldTJYdKjv7bnXVlpSgKz7mJnb2aciN1zT/CEBIsLHKHAQc3ysWzucYJ7LvRF/cXaEd9xMpcVVlkReIXAWTjESCpxGjFKqnJMO0wf/W8KnFmiyvSwbav2ED9GU2DWRYOPh01nYzhpPPjwB)

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
b‚€{11å
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6VHDrEdNa6oNDQ8v/f/f0NAAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/6RHDbMeNa2pNjQ8vPS/zv9oYx1LHUMLHUNLIx0jCwsdUyMDIDYxNjDRMTTUMTQAYkMDIG0A5hiAeGCugQFECgp0YCygEiAHKAM0DihsDMRmJpY6uoY6usZA0jAWAA).

`€{` could alternatively be `0м` for the same bytecount:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6VHDLIMLewwNDy/9/9/Q0AAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/6RHDbMMLuwxNDy89L/O/2hjHUsdQwsdQ0sjHSMLCx1TIwMgNjE2MNExNNQxNABiQwMgbQDmGIB4YK6BAUQKCnRgLKASIAcoAzQOKGwMxGYmljq6hjq6xkDSMBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
b        # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary string
 ‚       # Pair it together with the (implicit) input-integer
  €{     # Sort the digits in each string
    11å  # And check if this pair contains an 11 (which is truthy for "011","0011",etc.)
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)

  0м     # Remove all 0s from both the binary string and input in the pair
```

Comment: I'm just curious: if the number had three "1" then it would contain an 11, right?  But the code correctly doesn't match "111".  How does that work?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The `‚` creates a pair of the input with the binary-string of the input, so this pair is a list (of two items). So the `11å` in this case will check if **_item_** `11` (or `"11"`) is in this list. (Builtin `å` can also be used for checking substrings, in which case [`11å` with input `111` would indeed result in truthy](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0PDwUhBpCAA), but this doesn't apply in the above answer that checks for an item in a list.)

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 18 bytes

```apl
2∊+/↑(*3)2 10⊤¨0⌈⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/Ro44ubf1HbRM1tIw1jRQMDR51LTm0wuBRT8ejvqkgJf8VwKCAy4gLxjKGs0zhLENDJKYBEhshfmi9KQA)

Jo King's 18 byte solution.

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s><sup><sub>20</sub> 21 <sub>20</sub> 26</sup></s> 25 bytes

```apl
{<⍵:2∊+/↑(⊂×⍨⍎¨⍕⍵)⍪⊂⊤⍵⋄0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR71Y7AyujRx1d2vqP2iZqPOpqOjz9Ue@KR719h4DEVKC85qPeVUDhR11LgJxH3S0Gtf/THrVNAKp41NX8qHfNo94th9YbAzU/6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/pykYcaUpGAOxKRAbGoIJAzAJYh9abwoA)

+1 byte after correcting the answer(ovs).

-1 byte after ovs's suggestion.(yay!)

+7 bytes after properly accepting negative test cases.

-1 byte from Adám.

Inspired from the J solution.

### Explanation

```apl
{⍵>0:2∊+/↑(⊂2*⍨⍎¨⍕⍵)⍪⊂⊤⍵⋄0}
 ⍵>0:                       If number is positive
                      ⊤⍵    Decode number to binary
            ×⍨⍎¨⍕⍵          square each digit
         ↑ ⊂        ⍪⊂      join into two rows
       +/                   sum each row
     2∊                     is two present in it?
                         ⋄0 otherwise return 0
```

Comment: I think there might be another problem. For some reason I couldn't test it, but I think this returns `1` for negative inputs like `¯5`, so you need an `⍵>0` check (like the [J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211842/64121)).

Comment: it errors on negative inputs like `¯5` due to `⍕` and  `⍎` getting the digits. just needs a conditional.

Comment: Doesn't this fail to output 0 on negative numbers?

Comment: now it does. @Adám

Comment: Your score is a [mountain range series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199055/95126).

Comment: -10: `2∊+/↑√2 10⊤¨0⌈⎕` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/Ro44ubf1HbRMfdcwyUjA0eNS15NAKg0c9HY/6poJU/FcAgwIuIy4YyxjOMoWzDA2RmAZIbIT4ofWmAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: @DominicvanEssen :(

Comment: @JoKing reverted to the old solution.

Comment: You could have switched to cubing for [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/Ro44ubf1HbRM1tIw1jRQMDR51LTm0wuBRT8ejvqkgJf8VwKCAy4gLxjKGs0zhLENDJKYBEhshfmi9KQA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
ℕ{ḃc|}o11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f9Qytfrhjubkmtp8Q8P//6ONdSx1DC10DC2NdIwsLHRMjQyA2MTYwETH0FDH0ACEwYShAVDAwADENQCLQBgGcCEDkBIgBygDNAoobGZiqRNvqBNvHAsA)

Somewhat embarrassed I didn't think to translate other solutions' sort-based approaches earlier...

A more fun solution:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
ℕ{|ẹ~ḃ}ḃ+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f9Qytbrm4a6ddQ93NNcCsbbR///RxjqWOoYWOoaWRjpGFhY6pkYGQGxibGCiY2ioY2gAwmDC0AAoYGAA4hqARSAMA7iQAUgJkAOUARoFFDYzsdSJN9SJN44FAA)

```
ℕ             The input is a whole number (necessary to exclude -3 etc.),
 {|   }       which either unchanged or
   ẹ          with its decimal digits
    ~ḃ        interpreted as binary (impossible if any ≥ 2),
       ḃ      has binary digits
        +2    that sum to 2.
```

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
ℕ{ḃ|ẹ}<ᵛ²+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f9Qytfrhjuaah7t21to83Dr70CZto///o411LHUMLXQMLY10jCwsdEyNDIDYxNjARMfQUMfQAITBhKEBUMDAAMQ1AItAGAZwIQOQEiAHKAM0CihsZmKpE2@oE28cCwA)

-1 byte thanks to xash

```
ℕ              The input is a whole number,
 { | }         and either
  ḃ            its binary digits
    ẹ          or its decimal digits
      <ᵛ²      are all less than 2
         +2    and sum to 2.
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f9Qytfrhjuaah7t21to83Dr70CZto///o411LHUMLXQMLY10jCwsdEyNDIDYxNjARMfQUMfQAITBhKEBUMDAAMQ1AItAGAZwIQOQEiAHKAM0CihsZmKpE2@oE28cCwA)

Comment: Was sort of considering something like that, but never thought to superscript `ᵛ`--thanks!

Comment: Why does `+` not work on numbers and requires `ẹ`?

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte, and then -1 more byte, and then -2 more bytes, thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
gsub(0,'',n<-scan())!=11&sum(n%/%2^(0:n)%%2)-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdTgMhEIXveQqMWYGkRMCftI19E6OZRWqJ3aFh2Jg@/cpemCyrl9@ZM4cz5Gn6pLGXZiPEBl80eUCp1M3B2jsaB4ndfefepNmj6jqntJuenGHMQ5HiFYVi7JbnoL9zLIETDIHD5ZIT@BMH4scRfYkJeUk8AMXzlftT8F@8BCrcAwXas0jvmIrrYzn8@iUqtqhV6whrxf@F5gZ9RMjXRZJ8UEvaNWS3Le5cw27bzuvBqr7xEXwc4Nxs2jbIrPmPYE0rVMucjQn1LCxnK@dqr638/NheqFu7rr/B2PQD)

Tests for decimal 2bit numbers using text manipulation to remove '`0`' digits and check whether the result is *not* '`11`', and then tests for binary 2bit numbers by calculating the binary digits and checking if they *do not* sum to `2`.  Returns FALSE for 2bit numbers and TRUE for non-2bit numbers.
It seems a bit clunky to do two different kinds of tests for essentially the same feature, but somehow comes-out quite short...

Comment: Nice! You can save a byte by putting `n<-scan()` in the `gsub` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  How did I not realize that?

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY/BTsMwEETv/opFVbAt1cI2ULUV/ROEtDGGWjSbKusI9etDIpE4XLi9HY9nZ7th@OS@VnYr5ZZeDAckpfXdSTon77lvFFUPlX9T9ki6qrw2fnj2VoiAWclXklqIDXTRfHcpR2BsIuD12rUYzoAMHz2FnFqC3EJETpcbhHMMX5AjZwjIkY8isa9TPs1eRVqsSv1bZtpeJ8Lu9puiHvVMh4XcvuDBL@z3RR@P0mPWewypwcviduWjXfOfwdkyjE9TDrVkJmHWV46Vt1TZPZW2pljMeI0Qww8 "R – Try It Online") by inverting the output.

Comment: @RobinRyder that's neat.  I suppose we can always use ```-``` instead of ```!=``` for numeric comparisons, and so probably instead of ```==``` if (like here) there's a way to 'flip' the output.  Nice trick!

Comment: Precisely. That also works e.g. in `if` statements.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the quotes around `'11'` as the integer will get coerced to character (-2 bytes).

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!  I need to get my head around the coercion rules (or just be more adventurous trying-out removing quotes & seeing what'll happen)...

Answer (score 6):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>56</s> 52 bytes

*-4 bytes by successfully combining base \$2\$ and \$10\$ into a single expression, as was already accomplished in the other versions*

```
^((x)|(x))((((\2*)\3*)(\2\7){8}x(?=\6$))*x){2}\2{8}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BTsJAEIZfBRsCM8WWUhUN68LJAxcOerSabGBoV5ftZneBSttnr@Vg4iR/Mvm/SSbflzgJt7XS@MgZuSN7KPU3/XSWazoPXil/qQzAhS@nYfcJUGHTB6GfLA0xuwuxX7JHrJ/aClY8mw8RwwrrtM3Svht24fSCsS/fvJU6B4ydkluC@W10j8gcT9i5kIoAFLckdkpqAsQbro9KYZ1zFTujpIdxNEYm9wCa57EinfsCl2nTSLcRG5DcCOtorT3k78kH4h@g/0AvZ6vZ4orRF7Y8B2t9EkruBlbonBaDYKLYvrTA5DMnJicT7B8GVRBbMiQ8SIwPwm8LsIi1G41Mr@ThajFj5uidt/0Ja9suiR7S5Bc)

Takes its input in unary, as a sequence of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

Here are some examples of how this **52 byte** version works:

```
Example input: 1001000
Choose base 10 and subtract 1 from tail
1000999
Iteration 1 of the outer loop:
1000999
100099
10009
1000
tail -= 1
999
Iteration 2 of the outer loop:
999
99
9
tail -= 1
8
Assert tail == 10 - 2

Example input: 11
Choose base 10 and subtract 1 from tail  
10
Iteration 1 of the outer loop:
10
tail -= 1
9
Iteration 2 of the outer loop:
9
tail -= 1
8
Assert tail == 10 - 2
```

The regex, pretty-printed and commented:

```
^                # tail = N = input number
# Pick which base to operate in, and tail -= 1
(
    (x)          # \2 = 1 or unset (unset=0 due to ECMAScript NPCG behavior); B=10
|
    (x)          # \3 = 1 or unset (unset=0 due to ECMAScript NPCG behavior); B=2
)
# Assert tail is the sum of two powers of B
(
    (
        # tail = (tail + 1) / B - 1
        ((\2*)\3*)   # if \2=1, then \6 = \7 = (tail + 1) / 10 - 1;
                     # if \3=1, then \6 =      (tail + 1) /  2 - 1, and \7 = 0
        (\2\7){8}
        x
        (?=\6$)
    )*               # Loop the above zero or more times
    x                # tail -= 1
){2}                 # Loop the above exactly twice
\2{8}$               # Assert tail == B - 2
```

*The following text applies to the earlier 56 byte version:*

This turned out to be very similar to [Neil's 58 byte regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212103/17216). I looked at the byte count, but not at the regex itself, in that answer's heading before working on the problem myself. It took me a while to figure out how to make a non-ECMAScript-specific regex shorter than 70 bytes. The hangup for me was, that I was doing it like this:

```
^((((x+)\4{8}(?=\4$))*x(?=(xx)*$)){2}|(((x+)(?=\8$))*x(?=(xx)*$)){2})$
```

In order to prevent the loop from subtracting the same power of 2 or 10 twice (and matching, for example, 512 and 200) I had to use `(?=(xx)*$)` to assert that tail is even after subtracting 1 (this works for both 2 and 10, as they are both even). Finally I figured out that I could just use two alternatives inside the `(`...`){2}` loop, one that must do at least one division before subtracting 1, and one that can only subtract 1 if it's the first thing done, and this saved 7 bytes per base, giving 70 - 2×7 = 56 bytes:

```
^((((x+)\4{8}(?=\4$))+x|^x){2}|(((x+)(?=\7$))+x|^x){2})$
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>ECMAScript / Perl / PCRE / Java / Boost / Python / .NET</sup></sub>), 54 bytes

```
^(x?)(^x|\B)((((\1*)\2*)(\1\6){8}x(?=\5$))*x){2}\1{8}$
```

This is a port of the 52 byte ECMAScript version to be NPCG-behavior-independent and compatible with a wide variety of regex engines including ECMAScript (i.e., "generic"). This is done by changing `((x)|(x))` (where `\2` and `\3` are differently 1 or unset) to `(x?)(^x|\B)` (where `\1` and `\2` are differently 1 or 0).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Ba8JAFIT/ig2i78UmJqFKcbsKhR689NAemwqLPpNt182yu2pqzG9P46HQOQ3zDQzzJU7Cba00PnJG7sgeKv1NP53lms6DNypeagNw4ctp2G2gXiFs6mv@jNArT0PMsxB7k8@xeWxrWPF8NkQMa2yyNk/7bNiF0wvGvnr3VuoCMHZKbgnm99EDInM8YedSKgJQ3JLYKakJEO@4PiqFTcFV7IySHsbRGJncA2hexIp04UtcZterdK/iFSQ3wjpaaw/FR/KJ@AfoP9DLdJUubhh9aatzsNYnoeRuYIUuaDEIJortKwtMPnFicjLBfjCog9iSIeFBYnwQfluCRWzcaGT6Sx5uL1Jmjt5521dY23ZJNMuSXw) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5dS8MwFP0rYYQ1t2tpU6iIadZO5qtPvi1bmLJCIG41qRCJ8a/XrA68D5dzzv04ZzgZXU/vXwgbhry@vB01wgWLlDfbzctmHVB/MQRbXrJmzcAj1UcGfjDqPKKFOC9YQJ3mdtBqJEmeZPbz1Y7xRGY5zSicPq5L7b9aRh0esAR2/WWj49F0uqnAd3pH9zz2cs9uvupGsWr4PI5otQKvekRI4hLkUFwCQPwHFdgU4LFdLudwc7YYnLK/rFixEIKUT89bKacDcS2Qg/sWj0BiCZqCqFKIQNyBvw@OtFzUGCB14KsgaNTwNJV5XZW/) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDfa8IwEH73rwgh0JxWbYu6SSzC2AaDsYdtb0ZD7aItq2lIIxScf3t3lT0tcMf9@r7vcraw3WptC0uYIymhU0omxDp9VE7bKss1D6aT4VqpIqu8yuuTLSvtJJcg5Pu0CUISoB2wqI66HzBeG99wpZ5fXp@UgpDEgJRILAalKVWjPac2d3qyz/Jv79CpqjyVnoaEzpLlbLm4S5ZzCmJwqB1nZRoJVqUHZG/4x@fjyxsIuJDywFm1abyrtMEIxvE2Tak0FHC4Oe@xg@UwCscx9Hjd2qr@0pyOaYjjAvF5fTa@x64SBG2QAH20FQNCbsrmL2dmld76GI1GgNKE3y50ynxecOZCFOvPpTPPgzYImQEAculXLEHnRd3vJQh@JRakzwkz4ooy139n5SC6HW/XwHftj3wAjk/GQ5DJEDCQC7jcX1u@TuWcAQxbuCRXGWONdV00nifRLw) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLvb9sgEP3ev@JmdQo4KU0idZpGrWqdNqnSuk3txziViI0TUow9wI3TLH97djjej0rlC9zd4x3vcWvxJM7W@eNBlXVlPawxZqpiMYf/M41X@tWclUvZYuWkbhZaZZBp4RzcCmVgB33OeeFxe6pUDiVWyL23yixB2KWbzSn4la02Dj63may9qvDmCcAXpSUUiZGb7kgillW5ZFiPKL9uikJamd9JkUsLiw72Mkn@3OzDglLe93UjzzerwE@ISxaoQeRflZGE0jeJabSmqiCOyZ@N0I5E53EcR5TuXkKPDIT4Vwl2yOD/MiDBOTIsEPfI3TAZpGYQds/3x9z@h/BeWgM26U@otqxDA0c5urGoKi2FgeekQEbJ4T4TxqB0ZerGQwJBbZ8j91vnZcmUoRx6nR2MrYT7JluPz@wsBugN0fh25DiCDCJ6iX19NgeN5YBirtbKk@gMPwHxHswYKzfG4xhYVgvrJAZEz8ZzOgIzebXItDRLv7qcwhUEJHzAbTJHxmwl7Gze9nq6yEzmHD5aK7aOFUpr0o4G7aAzBaCobNCGz0jMmIO5TMwEt@EQBd4Kn63QoRLZLCuPEekm1@CAf0Ly48SwjRU16VtkVb39XtwJs5TYaTwylAalBZAS25scvQt/@0x7kyt0bGOVlyR8KuXPibdN@J9/5Ro99AWJ3roILaF8H9ZJmKrDA2mvKHlof6XXlOBKJzFNpzHFQ/qO7t7vW3KVpBenlMYt3U336QRzp4cwT4fx2cV0/Bs) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNtb9owEP7Or7ixqtgktIRuaEpIkSr1D0z7sInQKDUmsQZO5DgihfHXx85OYRkDf0h8b8/dPXdmRTFIGTt8FJKtqgWHyWuel/pe8ZTXd1lRPHbOTbxmvNAil/cLkaQSVYLFQi5ztU6MuoliWaIgLmZzCOFr92mz@fn6UP14e/v@LRtvMnJ4IfWUkpf6V/RECZ7I69No1Kd4icZ092Vfk2kYfb6htF/T3Wgfeai7OdBzpK4L/SKMC8cLWpUKrErxZP3YEVLDOhGSUNh1AE8xQ9OKS1LQgTcPhwFU6PMwijXkRjIBqbmUeuH76Ctkisqi0oGNZ7ksNVgqfN/SBIojWHDUlUgDy2CTJe8RyAwQA7sNhy5s@Qk85XolJCdWYEK6TR4aHGs1xwTKIbKY6FwQ63DHYqyLUOqC9Fwo8hLNjWUp5IL0Bj0anACkh1bj8yFs9@T70iinF3DBsf4OeBR8TP4Xy061b9JJvmmkmfQcbx7Amq9LrknpQq/umcKQkRKNhuJT/IkKEUrD9SSUXgCOI9odm6PV25nGcrEE0mY@LnmiWEZIqy96a7IOxNy1I3BxOpRewDribSlg66YV0oskEodj8oKL7s2c8krDZALif59957rE7FKQf7bn9JLglitFrzR8ucCzYsyn68OzUrnqBpdxOIWlQbIwrgEwWQOzkSc81LTxuub/Xu3l104sxpXGm1vzVVxXSgIuw/4wHIw/DX@z5SpJy8NgZRPEdqJ/AA) - Boost (throws some errors, but this is fixed in later versions than what is on TIO)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv/opF5LDr2sZySSl2RaC/YTkQWiVRUWWzUqlDmm93rZTuaZjhzc50iefRPy72cxo5QriEgk3xEUbfASsWQix7nHeE@/lHvxKup2VOuslpFfqJrs@3GXdKbzdE@UzX5qbl6m2WFe1lW8qhA6vq7DgyOLA@vahCfLe@zcApV4XJ2YiiFJSBPYIzHh29NC24Xg7K9fWQQYJ9gvngTwatj5gCKv6UHOhB0tqXCthUwRz47YxcgJhF7u9JimwLEyeE7oaS3f@a8StW32yjwRAZPdFSl9um/gU) - Python
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9BasMwELz7FYvIQevaxjIkBLsi0G_YDoRWTlRU2UgKVUjzkl5ySX_RQ5_R39Sy0z3NzjCzO59fw8kden39lm9DbxzYk02M2AufvNpeV2C4IYTcjq5L17-rLfUbpFv_0TwhHadhMTZFjCNoVnheXzzd8Ga5QIw9notLw0ZucXf_jEE1K1PWViB5HnW9AQVSh5uZdS9SlxEorjI7KOkoSQlGIDtQQlOFj0UJqmYtV3XeRhDMOpjNTu8FldrRIGAyI9biA8MxLwRMfTIrdub5QE0CxJNYT2JQZQmDCS6cCM6q_4f6o8vejXSCWmeoRpyLXG95uizyefkD) - Python (`import regex`)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9ha4MwEIb/isiBOV2KCh2jElq2z/sFxoK06QxkicQUQ11@u4sbY/fpnofj5d7RzMJOg1BqBctaKz6E7w4HLWZyytYz8UckZ//FX5HE4VWOvM4xLvwZl5fgyZHxPSDmHpc68Co6WLPTU/pmPkepxDXFBh6sbG7Giv4yEFCJ1AlIPd4dLtAzUHQalXQpTRt5I9DvLuauHVUuqbeDgkHfll2IAQQ0a6V23Y9pQFMl/rjauChw2TLs7r13l0FMJPNZDhp/9QOX2Uon6GAmF@JbVfPPCdUm1lZSiwR0CGEt6b4uvwE) - .NET

It [exposes a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17774) in the regex engine used by Ruby. The 56 byte regex works in Ruby: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ra8IwEMff9yluRTCZNKTFsUEWhuBe9yB7azU4jDUQzpJGzFD31WviphhI4H73/13O7b5/egcSZrrRoWWo9zCdfE2Y08uVACO5gP3GWA1WNtp3DwBmDbbKi7mUWY2ZiA1bccbyci5A4yomImFda40nw3xI/xVmNTZ@Q@hbGZ0q@lG7KeutAwSDkCDzW2VIwSljKXgrY@4yi2Qhe0IK8hecSMA8pj3bne8u89LeRaydQQ94/SK96Sr18TlVql@QeMKI1uPD64m8y3o8oHQUjotAD@Xp@NdM/OWe00Hf8/y55Gc)
But the 54 byte regex does not: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7Ra8IwEMbf91fcimCu0NAWHIMaRHGvexh7azRsGGsgxJJGzHDuX@8ushlIuO/L97s7f/r8Gj0IeNOdjj13@gzr5fuSe/2xa8CIsoHzwVgNVnQ6DA8AZg@2LaqNEJl0WUMfti05L@pNA9rtKEEOH3prApsWU/xDuNWuCweG85qYlnjC7sj@6MGBcZBMHo7KsKpEzlPwLil368WymOUOQfyAb5JhHtOe/SkMt35p74q0Ny6A@x@R3nSVenldKzVuWVwg28ZvuUJGR1Y5yjpHKuQTXp6vkS2EnE0Q84iX@ior8ibjWBazuvwF) Boiling this down, it appears that [`^((x*)(){4}(?=\2$))*x$`](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv@ytmi2BS6JCW9RSDCHr1sHirbtjFWANhLGnEyqJ/vSaiHmZg3rzvzfjT32XwoODbNKZvkcwZFvP1HL353UmwSkg4H6wz4FRjQvcBYPfg6qLcKpVtKJNx4WqBWFRbCYZ20REV7FpnAxsXY/5E0BlqwoHxaRWZOvIReyP7owcCS5BEDEdtWSk4YjK@x@h7ZLGsz3LioG7gZRLsZ/qzPYXukZf@LuPsLQWg14nUU2m9XC20Hn4Y63PO@P/Xlc3UphpxnvejYRDFpBJ3) matches powers of 2 just fine, but [`^((x*)(){5}(?=\2$))*x$`](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv@ytmi2BS6JAWPGWDCHr1IHurbtilsQbCWNKIFVn/ek1EPczAvHnfm/Gnv8voQcHGtGbokMwZlovvBXrz20iwSkg4H6wz4FRrQv8BYPfg6qLcKZVtKZNx4WqBWFQ7CYaa6IgK9p2zgU2LKX8i6Ay14cD4VxWZOvIReyP7owcCS5BEDEdtWSk4YjK@x@h7ZLFsyHLioG7gZRLsZ/qzO4X@kZf@LuPsLQWg14nUU2m9Wi@1Hn8YG3LO@HX2z@ZqW004z4fJOIpiVok7) does not.

Similarly, while it works with Python's `re` module (see above), it exposed a bug in the the more powerful `regex` module: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BasMwEETv/opF5LDr2sZySSh2RaC/YTkQWiVRUWQjqVQhzbe7lkv3NMzwZnenW7iM9nnW12l0AfzNF06dVSw@/Wg7cMIxxuYDxj3hIf7IN8JlJM9JNjktQu7o/vKIuBdyuyHKI92bh@SLt5kXtOdtyYcOtKiz0@jAgLZpS@XDh7ZtBkaYyk9GB2Qlowz0CYyyaOi1acH0fBCmr4cMEmwT7I72rFDbgCmg4k/xgZ44LX2pYP2guh7D@wVdASyy3K5ZCnULk0sQrYbg3f8941eovp0OCn1waInmutw29S8)    [This bug has [now been fixed!](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/commits/1e6986b92f978087eb34ca79732d3b0c45be8652)]

It also exposes a bug in older versions of Boost, as stated above – throwing an error on `480`, `512`, `584`, and many other larger numbers. In older versions of Notepad++ (using the older Boost versions), this is treated as a match.

## Regex (ECMAScript+`(?*)` <sub><sup>/ PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub></sup></sub>), <s>54</s> 47 bytes

```
^(?*(x)|(x))((((\1*)\2*)\6{8}(?=\5$))+x|^x){2}$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJfa9swEIc95lNchailxE7sQEeZIvyybBRGW7y91a1wPTnx4shGVsCQ5JPspTD2obpPs7OzP6wPE5x8d7_f7-50-Ou3Zt08_XgVL2J0gFqQQGYEptBYvVJWN1WWa-bNpuNYqXVWOZXX26astE1ZykWazFrPBw-twKRa6Z5gnDauZUq9u_qwVIr7EHEsiYXFqDSlarVjpMmtnj5m-cZZvFRVbktHfCBBRLiAf2lW5zvblrX5P-3LCQoRGRW1ZbSUoaCVLHCsln389Pbqmgu-h7JgtLprna20QY8H0b2UJDWEI7ndPSKCaT_0g4j3et01Vf1ZMxIQH-kC9Xm9M67XLuYousMCeIf3YgQwdDa_YmoWcsDRm0w47JEAOACwM0Y3ctjyNnP5mlHrY99-5TpzzOs8nxqOB6g-0aqsdUpbi-X5mZS3yfK9ur5RyyS5ScSfsnQDhwNqsFX_zJLrfF33bxOA64gE9DFQI45_J0HN-fmgGUDyBsj0RUu1bVeM922Oo-OLPwHz33euCC6fZw8sHrOOH9A4w5NGY57O0V7vL48slukF5XzSHR46vp8f6Un29PsTBhfz8BT8BA) - PCRE2

In this version, the two bases \$10\$ and \$2\$ are combined, by choosing between them using the initial `(x)|(x)`. Thanks to molecular lookbehind `(?*)`, this can be done without subtracting 1 from the number being tested:

```
^
(?*
    (x)          # \2 = 1 or unset (unset=0 due to ECMAScript NPCG behavior); B=10
|
    (x)          # \3 = 1 - \2; B=2
)
# Assert tail is the sum of two powers of B
(
    # Alternative #1: Divide evenly by B as many times as possible, at least once
    # (meaning tail has to be initially divisible by B), then subtract 1.
    (
        ((\1*)\2*)\6{8}(?=\5$)   # assert tail % B == 0; tail /= B
    )+
    x                            # tail -= 1
|
    # Alternative #2: Don't divide at all, and just subtract 1, but only if this is
    # the first thing we do. If this path is taken, only alternative #1 can next.
    ^x                           # assert tail == N; tail -= 1
){2}             # Loop the above exactly twice
$                # Assert tail == 0
```

When `\1`=1 and `\2`=0, `((\1*)\2*)\6{8}(?=\5$)` behaves like `(x*)\5{8}(?=\5$)`, dividing by \$10\$.
When `\1`=0 and `\2`=1, `((\1*)\2*)\6{8}(?=\5$)` behaves like `(x*)(?=\5$)`, dividing by \$2\$.

## Regex (ECMAScript 2018 <sub><sup>/ Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / .NET</sup></sub>), 51 bytes

```
((x)|(x))$(?<=^(x((?<=^\6)\7{8}(\3*(\2*)))+|x$){2})
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBPa8JAEMW/igRhZ4xZkpT@IXH11IMXD@2xaXFJ1jhl3aS7qwYSP7tNhYKHYQZ@M@895luepCsttT4yTaWuTsS5FW@qfu1aePeWTM2tPG@vAB0OY@EUVgvxBR3cevGExXP/coHiYQZFOkPEcOim2KcXvG6501QqSOZRgnN2YJhb9XMkq4BZJStNRjHk5Th7tTZe2Z0c13sy7dFnrW1K5Rx3viJzQd4YYLeLuRbLvhaau1aTBxaNurQDMKLmWpna73GZDgO5jdwAiVZa96cO9Uf8ifgP1D0wy2SVZH8Y/d4252BtTlJTNbHS1CqbBKHOd42FnBZC5RSGOBoGXcCtasfwQMgP0pd7sIj9XfDm6PnZklcAbsUKwzLGMCTMnUjyy/iiOHpM418) - ECMAScript 2018 (Node v11.6.0, with bug workaround)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDBboJAEIbTF2mMMdkZkQ1g2hpw9dSDFw_tsbSRwIKb0IXuLpUEeJJePNR36Ku0T1PUmHiYzEy--Wf-zNe3LBK-_9HMCRR74tljXcKzUUJmVEW7zaEyqT37nQLU2PaBI1jO2RvUcMrhPYYPzayDcDqG0BsjotXWI2y8Ds_Sv5vbDdW5iDm4E9tFDBT_qITiQBSPklxITpDGfW34Shqu0qgfbYQsK-OXqoi51lSbRMgOaSGBnBSTnC2ajOVUl7kwQGyCgUgBJMtozmVmtrjw2lbodbQGwcpI6eN2yF6cV8QL4NdALtyl6x8xmq0qdsOV_IxykQxUJDPuD4ZWHqSFgkDMGQ-EZWF_cFgPqeJlbx4E0vfIxFtQiM2V8aIydKeE4QB6SUJJfELQEhho5gbd5U37g2Pfec65-Qc) - ECMAScript 2018 (Node v17.3.0+, bug fixed)**
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9NboMwEIX3nGJkZTFDAAFR2whi9SBApag1iSvXINtRiZKcpJts0lt00WP0NsUkWYzm5-l7M_P13e_dttPnH_nRd8aB3dvIiI0Yonfb6RIMN4yxy8618fJvgTjQcQya4fOKv-CAU64fqX46LE9YL0Ks85CI5sdhRof8RDf0d3SpsiLOmhIkT4O2M6BAar8wse5N6iIAxVVieyUdsphRALIFJTQqWuUFqCpruKrSJgAPaw-btd4IlNqhFyi6VllD84xGP28wPZNYsTavWzQRsIGFehK9KgvojadoGvCsvB_U7VzyaaQTaJ1BTbdHzpc0fsjTa_MP) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/vaoQwEMRfRWTBXW0Oz9I/nA096Oc@gVoINlcDaSIxh3Jent3qldIPy/AbhmGnt6N0Qye1XsDxyskvOTWHg5EjHpMFcaLregT4@sI/cMKb1o9UP83PAev7FOsiJaLsOgHNRaAlOd7Fb/a7V1p@xlTCheflyTop2g5BR8pEoEx/9jSD4KDZ0GvlYxaX6oQgdq09G8@0j4otkHEQVd6EtQDB8EoZ39ycEgzT8o/3G2cZzVuH270L33ZywGRKUjD0a19oHp3yknV28GF9a1/@c8SMXTdrZWQEJoSw5OyhyH8A) - .NET

This is a port of the ECMAScript+`(?*)` version to variable-length right-to-left-evaluated positive lookbehind `(?<=)`. It starts 1 off from the end, reaches the end by capturing a determination of whether to work in base \$10\$ or \$2\$, then does the rest of its work going backwards.

It [**exposed a bug**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57527758#57527758) present in the ECMAScript 2018 regex engine of both SpiderMonkey (Firefox) and V8 (Chrome / Node). To make this regex work, the **m**ultiline flag must be enabled. [It fails to work without the flag.](https://tio.run/##TZBPa8JAEMW/igRhZ4xZkpT@IevqqQcvHtpj0@KSrHFKukl3Vw3EfHYbhYKH4Q385s085lsdlSsstT4yTakvTsbCyjddvXYtvHtLpuJWnbYXgA7PY@EUVgv5BR3cNH/C/Ll/GSB/mEGezhAxPHdT7NMBL1vuaio0JPMoQRRW/x7IamBWq7ImoxnyYuy9Xhuv7U6Noz2Z9uCz1jaFdo47X5IZkDcG2M0xr@Wyr2TNXVuTBxYxFLQDMLLitTaV3@MyPZ/JbdQGSLbKuut2qD7iT8R/oO@BWSarJLti9HvbnIK1OaqayolVptLZJAhrsWssCFpILSgMcTwYdAG3uh3DAyH/Ub7Yg0Xs74I3B89PlrwGcCuWG5YxhiGhcDIRw/ieOHpM4z8) pxeger [has reported the bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11616). It was since then fixed.

```
(
    (x)          # \2 = 1 or unset (unset=0 due to ECMAScript NPCG behavior); B=10
|
    (x)          # \3 = 1 - \2; B=2
)
$                # head = N = input number
# Assert head is the sum of two powers of B
(?<=             # Lookbehind - evaluated right-to-left
    ^            # Assert head == 0
    (
        # Alternative #1: Divide evenly by B as many times as possible, at least once
        # (meaning head has to be initially divisible by B), then subtract 1.
        x                             # head -= 1
        (
            (?<=^\6)\7{8}(\3*(\2*))   # assert head % B == 0; head /= B
        )+
    |
        # Alternative #2: Don't divide at all, and just subtract 1, but only if this is
        # the first thing we do. If this path is taken, only alternative #1 can next.
        x$                            # assert head == N; head -= 1
    ){2}     # Loop the above exactly twice
)
```

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Boost / Python / Ruby / .NET), <s>51</s> 39 bytes

```
^()?(((x*)(?(1)\4{8})(?=\4$))+x|^x){2}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5BasMwEPzKEkSsrW1smQRKZcUOpNeeeqsTkZYYBGriSi6oqOrXXcUN9LLMzM7uzHAyej29fwExHLy@vB01kIJHKurd9nm7CdBfDCVWlLzecPSg@sjQD0adR1h05wUP0GphB61GmuRJZj9f7RhPZJazjOHp42pq/tUy6vhAJPLrLxsTj6bVdYW@1S9sL@Is9/yWq26UqFrM64jSFL3qgdLEJeAgmhBB/EBBTIGe2OVyLjd3i8UZ/@tKFA8hSPn4tJNyOlBsKKXuDmlDGXYrfx8iFN2KIKbu@@DQV4FMU5mvq/IX) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNa8JAEL37K5ZlITMaNQnaVtbgpS0USg9tb0aXmK4mNG6WzQoB62@3E@mphx3efLz3ZseW9rpc2dIy4VjK@JSzCbNOH5TTts4LDcF0MlwpVea1V0VztFWtXQYZyux92gYhC@jtqagOuh8wXhvfglLPL69PSmHIYiRJEpaDylSq1R64LZye7PLi2zsKqq6Olech47NkMVvc3SeLOUc52DcORJVGUtTpntRb@Ph8fHlDiWdW7UHU69a7WhtCOI43acozw5GG29OOOlQOo3AcY8/Xna2bLw18zEMal8QvmpPxPXeZEGlNAhSjjRwwdnM2f7kwy/TWJzQaIVkzuF3omPuiBOFCMuvPpXMPQReEwiAiO/crVqiLsun3koy@EkvW50wYeSGby7@zAsrrFnAFAN0QYQUxZrPzw4Vgms0E4qj72XZ4Ti7ieo3G8yT6BQ) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNdb9owFH3nV9yxqtgkaUmLqikhRZq0PzDtYROlUWpMYg2cyHFEgPHXx66dkjEW/JDY9@Pce861WVF4KWPHj0KyVbXgMHnL81LfK57y@i4riufepYvXjBda5PJ@IZJUokmwWMhlrtaJMTdZLEsUxMVsDhF87X/ebH6@PVY/ttvv37KnTUaOr4ROCSH1kJIp8enLeP/pgNvoZXxDqVP/eq3p/uFwc6SXqX0XhkUUF44fnrUmsA3Fk/VzT0gN60RIQmHfA1zFDF0rLklBPX8ejUKoMObxIdaQm5NJSM2m1IsgwFghUzQWlQ5tPstlqcFyDwKrCyiOYOHJViJvlsEmS94zUAogBnYXjVzY8RY85XolJCf2wIR0mzo0PPVqlkmUI5Qt0bkgNuCOxdgXodQF6btQ5CW6G89SyAUZeAMatgDSR6@J@RCdcwoCaYzTDlxwbLwDPoUAi//FsmMcmnKSb5rTTPqOPw9hzdcl16R0YVAPTGOoSIlOI3Gb30ohImm0nkTSD8FxxDljs7TaXlisFksg58rHJU8Uywg540VvTVVPzF07AhenQ2kH1glvRwGpGypk8CJROByTH3aGN3PKKw2TCYj/Yw696ydmLwX55/a0TwduuVL0CuHuBi@aMZ9@AF@UylU/7MbhFJYGycK4BsBUDc2NbPHQco7XN//3brufN7EYV4g3u@aruK6UBLwMh@PIexqPfrPlKknLo7eyBWI70T8) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RasMwDEXf8xXC9EFqkxBnHYxkph@SplA2t/XwlCB7LKXrt2dxx94uOvdcNF7jZeCn2X2Og0QI15CLzT/CwC2IEaXUfEDaIeK0Jtyhpv329nJfotlvV0Sb6ecw0a2@r@al2@mm0H0LzlTZaRDw4DhtliG@O24y8MaXYfQuoioUZeBO4C2jp9e6Ad/p3viu6jNIMidZjny26DhiApT/Jd3TRtOylwbElsEe5e2CkoOa1JofJCHXwChJocfB6Pb/m@Erlt/iosUQBZlorornuvoF) - Python
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BbsIwEEX3OcXIQuoMJFEcUQkltThICBJqHXDlOpFt1CDKSbphQ2_RRY_R2zRO6G5m_rw_8z-_upM_tOb6rd661npwJxdbuZd9_OpaU4IVljF2O_omWf0-bJHWiNjPCdfIabM8ry5DKTbLGdGi_9j2dM4vs_v6z0BWvEh4XYISWdS0FjQoE46kzr8oU0SghU5dp5VHljCKQDWgpUFNT3kBuuK10FVWRxBgE2C7M3uJyngMAsVTxWtacBr8gsEYIHVyZ58PaGNgPZubUQyqKqCzgaJxIHj5_1B79Om7VV6i8xYN0RTkesuSxzybmj8) - Python (`import regex`)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BasMwDIbvewotFCp1xDihg4FnSqG77jB2S1qzUTc1GDc4LvXoulfP7LL1ICH9@j9J/vj5NXqQ8KY7HXvm9AlWy/cl8/pjK8BILuC0N1aDlZ0Owx2A2YFtymotZdG6QqSBbThjZb0WoN02OZLCht6agNNySn8Is9p1YY/0XCemSXzCbsju4MGBcZBFFg7KYMWJsWy8tcl33YVFLGaOQP6AF1kw9/nP/hiG6778d5V6b1wA938i5xxKvbyulBo3SAtEjDPCBVbUzs9Pl1TKdj4heojfm0jn@jIZR14@1vwX) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/haoNAEIRfRWTBvdgLKimUyJFAf/cJjAGxm3pw3ZPzghJ7z261pfTffMMwzPR2JDd0ZMwCTlWOPmiqj0emEc/JckVxQsRpJ/CEubgc5pewSnU5gBDp9HWdxFwEWJLzU/xqP3tt6D0WJTxUVt6so6btEEykOQLN/d2LGRoFRg690T6WcalvCM2@tXf20vio2AKpgqbK6rAWILCqNPv6xymBpaE/zjdOUzFvHW7/1vi2owGTKdkBi1/7IebRaU@ys4MP66y8/OdIsl1/Gs0UAYcQlkw@F9k3) - .NET

This version takes advantage of a conditional group `(?(1)\4{8})` to determine whether to work in base \$10\$ or \$2\$.

```
^
()?              # \1 = choose between B=10 (if set) or B=2 (if unset)
# Assert tail is the sum of two powers of B
(
    # Alternative #1: Divide evenly by B as many times as possible, at least once
    # (meaning tail has to be initially divisible by B), then subtract 1.
    (
        (x*)(?(1)\4{8})(?=\4$)   # assert tail % B == 0; tail /= B
    )+
    x                            # tail -= 1
|
    # Alternative #2: Don't divide at all, and just subtract 1, but only if this is
    # the first thing we do. If this path is taken, only alternative #1 can next.
    ^x                           # assert tail == N; tail -= 1
){2}             # Loop the above exactly twice
$                # Assert tail == 0
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE /</sup></sub> Java <sub><sup>/ Boost / Python / Ruby / .NET</sup></sub>), 44 bytes

```
^()?(((x*)(\1\4{8}|(?!\1))(?=\4$))+x|^x){2}$
```

**[Try it online! - Java](https://tio.run/##bVLbbtswDH3vV7BGh1C5uEnRAcNUI9iGDRiwbkP7mKSAYsuJUln2JLlxm@bbM8rxLgXqF5rk0aHOETfiQYw22f1BFVVpPWwoj1UZ9zn8X6m90q/WrFzJhjonVb3UKoVUC@fgWigDO@hqzgtP4aFUGRTUwVtvlVmBsCs3WzDwa1tuHXxuUll5VdLJE4AvSkvIEyO37S9GcVpmMqZ@xPjHOs@lldmNFJm0sGxhL4v452SX5ozxbq4ber5dB35ElyxJg8i@KSORsdPE1FozlaOL5a9aaIfReb/fjxjbvYQeGRD9qwQ7YvB/GYjgnBiWhLvnbpD05qYXouf7Y23/U3gvrQGbdH@ktqjCAMc4ubEsSy2FgackJ0bJ4TYVxpB0ZaraQwJBbVfD20fnZRErwzh0OltYvBbuu2w8XbO1GKAzRNPdieMIMoToJHb92QI0tQMqdpVWHqMRPQLhPZgxdb4aT2tg40pYJylBPRsv2BDM5NVmrKVZ@fXVBUwhIOE9hcmCGNO1sLNF0@lpMzNZcPhgrXh0ca60xmbYa3qtKQB5aYM2ukZixhzMVWImFAYDEngtfLomhwpis3FxzLDdXEML/onIjxsTb62osBuRltXjj/xGmJWkSeOhYSwozQELGm8y8i687RPrTC7Jsa1VXmJ4VMafEm/r8D7/2hV56HOM3riILGF8H76TsFWHO2RTRGz6DOeT@eXu3f4Zp6fzCWM4TeaXZ4wNmue7hu0u9meHsEWH8ejtxfg3)** / [Perl](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/yp0Em7u2tCkKsjS2gnvd095WDU4sBDLtkg46YvbVu9gJe7ncc@6f8@tORi/Hj28ghoPTl@NBA8l4kKLcbl43aw/txVBiRc7LNUcHqg0KXWfUuYdZc55xD7UWttOqp1EaJfbr3fbhRCYpSxiePm9L1b@bBx@fiER@@2VD4sHUuizQ1fqN7USo@Y7fc9VdElWKaRy6OEanWqA0GiIYICwhgviBjJgMHbHz@QQ3sQVwxv9YieLeeymfX7ZSjnuKFaV0eETasGbhVv5Kq4eGIdJKNAuCGA/X/YCu8GQc83RZ5L8) / [PCRE](https://tio.run/##XVDLasMwELznK1Qh8G7iJLZJH0ExvrSFQumh7S1OhesqtakjC1kBQ5JvT9ehpx607GtmVmMre15ltrJMOJYyPudsxqzT38pp2xSlhmA@G2dKVUXjVdnubN1ol0OOMn@dd0HIAnpbaqpvPSwYr43vQKnHp@cHpTBkMRIlEctRbWrVaQ/clk7PPovyxzsKqql3tech44tkuVje3CbLa45ytG0diDqNpGjSLbF38PZ@//SCEg@s3oJo1p13jTaU4TTepCnPDUda7vafNKF2GIXTGAe87m3TfmngUx7SuiR82e6NH7CrhEBrIqAYbeSIsYuy@auFWaWXOWWTCZI0g4tDu8KXFQgXkthgly48BH0QCoOI7DCcWKMuq3a4SzL6SizZUDNh5IlkTv9sBZTnD8AMAPoxQh7ni8Pd6QjZVR4jQpbmC4E46Y8fPR6Skzifo@l1Ev0C) / [Boost](https://tio.run/##dVNtb9owEP7Or7iyqtgkaUmLqikhRZq0PzDtwyagUWpMYg0cy3FEgPLXx2ynZBkL/pD43p67e@5MhPBSQk6fGCfrcklh8pbnhXqQNKXVfSbES@/SRCtChWI5f1iyJOVaxUjM@CqXm8So6yiSJRJiMVtABN/6X7bbX29P5c/d7sf37HmbodMrwlOEUDXEaO7Px4fPx3c0vZn7GKNpNB/fYuxU768VPjweb0/4Mr7vwlBEsXD8sFUf07VImmxeeowr2CSMIwyHHugjZtq0phwJ7PmLaBRCqX2eHmMFuZFMQGouhVoGgfZlPNVKUarQxpOcFwosAUFgyQFJNVh41hW6eZLBNks@IjQfgAzsPhq5sKcNeErVmnGKrEAYd@s8ODzXao4J5CPNXaJyhqzDPYl1XQhjF7jvgsgLba4tK8aXaOANcNgAcF9bjc9N1O4pCLhRTjtwwbH@DvgYAp38L5ad5dCk43RbSzPuO/4ihA3dFFShwoVBNTCFaUYKbTQUN/ENFSzihutJxP0QHIe1OzZHyd2FxnKxAtRmPi5oIkmGUKsvfGeyemzh2hG4ejoYd2Cd8fYYdOumFTSYc02cHpMfdrrXc8pLBZMJsP99jr3rErFLgf7Znub9wB2VEl9puLvAi2LMpx/AVylz2Q@7cSiGlUGyMK4BMFlDs5ENnta08frm/1Ft9xtHFuNK4/Wt/kqqSslBL8PxNPKex6PfZLVO0uLkrW2C2E70Dw) / [Python](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3PsVUZDGT2MZyUih2hQ9iOxBapVFRJTNSqUOSs7tRSnfDf7zHTOd48m67mK/Jc4RwDjnr/DN41wIrFkIse6QOEec14SCH3eXldsXuaZBE2KlhtyLazNf9TJf6tlruQi@bQo4tGFVlR89gwbgULkN8N67JwCpbhsmaiKIQlIE5gtUOLb3WDdhejsr21ZhBkl2S@eA@NBoXMQHK/y450kbSvZcCrMugD/x2Qs5BzGLtHiQh08DESaHHoGT7/43/juUPm6gxREZHtFTFc139Ag) / [Ruby](https://tio.run/##PY5Ba8MwDIXv@xVqKFTqiLFDB4PMhEJ33WHsFrdho25qMG5wXJrRdn89s8vWgwR6et@T/PHre/Qg4V23euiY0ydYLT@WzOvPbQlG8hJOe2M1WNnq0D8AmB3YOhdrKTPlsjIubM0Zy4t1CdptoyMqrO@sCTjLZ/SHMKtdG/ZIL0Vk6shH7I7sDh4cGAdJZOHQGBScGEvG@xh9tyzMhmzuCOQP@DIJZpL@7I6hv@Wlv0WcvXEB3P@J1FM1zevbqmnGDVKFiMOcUAm1OD9fL1hNlCDCSqrFlOhxuGwGOhfX6Tjy/Kngvw) / [.NET](https://tio.run/##RY/haoMwFIVfxckF761NUelgVIKF/d4TqAVx6QykicQUpTbP7nRj7Od3OHyc05tR2KETSi1geWnFl5jq00mLEc/RckEqEHHaEVZpdZzf/BOLlyolwoJXRyCKp@dlojnzsETnffhubr1U4jOkHB48ya/GiqbtEFQgdQBS93dHMzQcFBt6JV3IwlxeEZpDa@7aMeWCbCvEHJoyqf0qQNC8lNrVP0kOminxx@nGcUzz5rCHj8a1nRgwmqIdaPqNHzSPVjrBOjM4v85K838OmDbrWSW1CEB775eEvWbJNw)

```
^(()|())(((x*)(\2\6{8}|\3)(?=\6$))+x|^x){2}$
```

**[Try it online! - Java](https://tio.run/##bVLvb9owEP3ev@IWdeIMNAWmVdPcqNqmTZq0blP7EahkEgdMHSeznZKW8rezc8h@VCJfLnf3/M7v@dbiQZyts/u9KqrSelhTHqsy7nP4v1J7pY/WrFzKhjonVb3QKoVUC@fgWigDW@hqzgtP4aFUGRTUwVtvlVmCsEs3nTPwK1tuHHxuUll5VdLJE4AvSkvIEyM37S9GcVpmMqZ@xPjHOs@lldmNFJm0sGhhL4v452SX5ozxbq4ber5ZBX5ElyxIg8i@KSORsVeJqbVmKkcXy1@10A6j836/HzG2fQk9MCD6owRbYvB/GYjgnBgWhLvnbpD0ZqYXoue7Q233U3gvrQGbdH@ktqjCAMc4ubEoSy2FgackJ0bJ4TYVxpB0ZaraQwJBbVfD20fnZRErwzh0OltYvBLuu2w8XbO1GKAzRNPdieMAMoToJHb96Rw0tQMqdpVWHqMzegTCezAj6nw1ntbAxpWwTlKCejqasyGY8dFmrKVZ@tXlBK4gIOE9hfGcGNOVsNN50@lpMzOec/hgrXh0ca60xmbYa3qtKQB5aYM2ukZiRhzMZWLGFAYDEngtfLoihwpis3FxyLDdXEML/onIDxsTb6yosBuRltXjj/xGmKWkSaOhYSwozQELGm8y8i687RPrTC7JsY1VXmJ4VMafEm/r8D7/2hV56HOMXruILGF8F76TsFX7O0T2TJSI2PQZziazi@273fPsDcOrZHZxytigeb5r2HayO92HLdqPzt5ORr8B)** / [Perl](https://tio.run/##RY7LasMwEEV/ZQginqlt/CgJpbISB9JtV93ViUhLDAI1cSUXXGT1110lDXQzzL3zuKc7Gr2YPr6BGQ5On98PGljGgxTVdvOyWXlozwaZFTmvVpwcqDYocp1Rpx5mzWnGPdRa2E6rHqM0SuzXm@3DiUzSIino@HlZWv@7efDpkUnil182JB5MrauSXK1fi50INd/xW666SaYqcR2HLo7JqRYQoyGCAcISEYgfyJjJyDE7n1/hrmwBvOB/rExx772UT89bKac9Io1IhIjDHWFTNkv34MfmnnAtmiUjiodxP5ArPZumPF2U@S8) / [PCRE](https://tio.run/##XVBNa8JAEL37K5ZlITMaNabWVtbgpS0IpYe2N9Muabqa0LhZNisE1N@eTqSnHnaYr/fe7LOF7VZrW1gmHEsYn3I2YdbpvXLaVlmuIZhOhmuliqzyKq8Ptqy0SyFFmb5OmyBkAb0dNdVe9wvGa@MbUOpp8/yoFIZshkRJxHJQmlI12gO3udOTryz/8Y6CqspD6XnI@DxezpeLu3h5y1EOdrUDUSaRFFWyI/YG3t4fNi8o8cTKHYhq23hXaUMZjmcfScJTw5GWm@MXTagdRuF4hj1et7aqvzXwMQ9pXRI@r4/G99hVTKAtEVCMPuSAsauy@auFWSXXOWWjEZI0g6tDh8znBQgXklhvl848BG0QCoOI7NSfWKLOi7q/SzL6ykyyvmbCyAvJXP7ZCii7TwA8AyIAtEOENE4Xp/vLOb1BWCfpQiCO2vNni6f4IrouGt/G0S8) / [Boost](https://tio.run/##dVNtb9owEP7Or7ixqtgkaQlMaEpIK03aH5j2YRPQKDUmsQaO5TgiFPjrY7ZTsowFf0h8b8/dPXcmQngpIeePjJNNuaIwe83zQj1KmtLqIRPiqXdtohWhQrGcP65YknKtYiRmfJ3LbWLUdRTJEgmxmC8hgm/9L7vdr9dJ@XO///E9m@4ydH5BCB8RxgihaojRYryYHj6fjosJRs/RYnqHsVMdXyp8GJ/uzvg6vu/CUESxcPywVR/TtUiabJ96jCvYJowjDIce6CPm2rShHAns@ctoFEKpfSbjWEFuJBOQmkuhVkGgfRlPtVKUKrTxJOeFAktAEFhyQFINFl50hW6eZLDLkvcIzQcgA/sWjVx4ow14StWGcYqsQBh36zw4vNRqjgnkI81donKGrMMDiXVdmjIXuO@CyAttri1rxldo4A1w2ABwX1uNz4eo3VMQcKN87sAFx/o74GMIdPK/WHaWQ5OO010tzbnv@MsQtnRbUIUKFwbVwBSmGSm00VDcxDdUsIgbrmcR90NwHNbu2Bwl91cay8UaUJv5uKCJJBlCrb7wvcnqsaVrR@Dq6WDcgXXBe8OgWzetoMGCa@L0mPyw072eU14qmM2A/e9z6t2WiF0K9M/2NO8H7qmU@EbD3QVeFWM@/QC@SpnLftiNQzGsDZKFcQ2AyRqajWzwtKaN1zf/92q73ziyGDcar2/1V1JVSg56GU7nkTf9NPpN1pskLc7exiaI7UT/AA) / [Python](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3PsUgsphJbGM5NBQ7ogexHQit0qgokhmp1CHO2d0opbvhP95jxms8e7ddzGX0HCFcQ846/wretcCKhRDLAZFmJELEaU3Y1/3u9nqf@y3hm@p3K6LNNB8mutX31fIQOtkUcmjBqCo7eQYLxqVwGeKHcU0GVtkyjNZEFIWgDMwJrHZoaV83YDs5KNtVQwZJdknmo/vUaFzEBCj/u@RAG0mPXgqwLoM@8vsZOQcxibV7koRMAyMnhZ6Dku3/N/47lj9sosYQGR3RUhUvdfUL) / [Ruby](https://tio.run/##PY5Ba8MwDIXv@xVaKFTqiEk8VgaZGYXuusPYLWnNRt3UYNzguNSj6f56Zpe1Bwn09L4nucP3z@hAwIdqVeiYVUdYLj4XzKmvTQVaFBUcd9ooMKJVvr8D0FswdV6uhMgam1VxYeqCsZyvKlB2Ex1RYX1ntMdpPqV/hBllW79DeuGRqSMfsRuy3TuwoC0kkfm91FgWxFgy3sbou2RhFrKZJRC/4Kok6Pv0Z3fw/SUv/V3G2WnrwV5PpJ5Kyrf3pZTjGpEGJELEMCNseDM/PZ@H5pHwVTTzCdFDGNaBTvw8Gccif@LFHw) / [.NET](https://tio.run/##RY/haoMwFIVfReSC99alWMfKqIQV9ntPoBbEpjOQJRJTlMY8u9ONsZ/f4fBxTm9GYYdOKLWA5aUVn2KqTyctRjwnywWRZiRCxGlHWOXV0b@GuXomfOPVEYjSab5M5PMAS3J@it/NVy@VuMZUwINnxc1Y0bQdgoqkjkDq/u7IQ8NBsaFX0sUsLuQNodm35q4dUy7Kt0LKoSmzOqwCBM1LqV39kxSgmRJ/fNg4TclvDrv/aFzbiQGTKdmBpt/4QX600gnWmcGFddah@OeIabOeVVKLCHQIYcnYS559Aw)

These are ports of the 39 byte version, to a regex flavor that has no conditionals. In the first one, the `(?(1)\4{8})` conditional is replaced with `(\1\4{8}|(?!\1))` which behaves equivalently at a cost of 5 extra bytes. In the second the expression `(()|())` instead of `()?` is used to determine the mode (which either sets `\2` or `\3` leaving the other one unset), and the conditional is replaced with `(\2\6{8}|\3)`. The regex is otherwise unchanged (except for shifting the capture group numbering).

Comment: As a pure .NET regex, I could do it in 46 bytes, if I could be bothered to golf down the last few bytes from `(?<=(?=((((1+)(?(5)\4{8})(?=\4$))+|^)1){2}$)^(1)?)` (it's just tedious which is why I haven't bothered.)

Comment: @Neil That regex doesn't work and it's 50 bytes, so 46 is an oddly specific byte count to conjecture on. But yeah, I hadn't tried with conditionals yet, I was too much in the ECMAScript mindset at the time.

Comment: The regex works fine when I try it, but I was imaging that it would be 46 bytes as I could reverse the entire regex which would leave me with a lookahead which I could then remove, but I may have got that byte count wrong. Anyway, your `^()?` capture is the superior way of implementing the conditional, so that's a moot point now.

Comment: My bad, 50 byte regex actually [does work](https://tio.run/##ZVBdSysxEH33V8QiNMN@sFsqXIyxFxYfBEWxgg9XhdztWANpdslk69ptf3tNd9UX52nCOZPzUVJSVg73Vq2QalUim3@Qx1XXkLZLVsiislQZFMP7AVuf3uOyMcpdtrVDIh0IojSKiK068srrkq0rvWA3SlvGoVsrx0j@He357FzymeRh8gj4jJ/C07T7swurfJqeAETbF8ihm@xO4IXnMIP9SByunbT4zoIstpzSefOfvAtueB5Teo126d@SCcQ9flv7g6G0qFa1NrgAMXCZEa@V49p6ZmUmuJFFyKEW19oiBziWtjFGWBnk9Su3FxkU6aPTHgdCb6OWJp3XRns@TsYgDn/pGMVROKi/fFxMttvjAKQP7uNOOUJe/8ue46oJVPgNfZ8l@cBB@Jbloyu7VibU6JRd4hnrst0oNiDQEPaVtn0p86GJcT6ONfxE3ISI@lyi0FEUt5EMMASXLr2iG@XLN95Cn3PzK@dG5uLHQq/ZfnkEsetnnyWnk@wT) it's the `x`/`1` difference

Comment: the 39-byte regex works for Julia, if you want to add it [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBasMwEETv@oqNyGG3jcEyKZRQN@dee01iEI1iq2w3RlaoIMm3u1J76WGHHebxPi/srUlzaIP91lrPHdIWEdMD4RYN7dfX53t@2/16SfSYbl2ia3NfzpndmY2TY2UOt9d317ukTucADF4gOHtkL25CUsDtNLKPyCtd6dz9CdhJHwdkemkUwHiZhkWeeWcOec9OBUUlRTXaMDl8k/g3b/73puDFh182fgwYVjrpTohg0YKc4@ClzwCMwUtkQSn4r75EvrmunppaGVPXPw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: @MarcMush Indeed, Julia uses PCRE as its regex engine.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
₍fb3eṠ2c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLDt+G5oShuzrsiLCLigo1mYjNl4bmgMmMiLCI74oCgW24sXSkiLCJbLTMyLDI1Nl0iXQ==)
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oKNZmIzZeG5oDJjIiwiIiwiM1xuOVxuMThcbjE5MlxuMjg4XG41MjBcbjUyNDMwNFxuMTFcbjEwMVxuMTAwMVxuMTAxMFxuMTEwMFxuMTAwMDAwMVxuMTEwMDAwMDAwMFxuMTAwMDAwMDAxMFxuMFxuMVxuMTEyXG4yMDBcbjY0OVxuLTFcbi0zIl0=) - test cases only

```
₍    # Parallel Apply Wrap - applies the following two operations to the input,
     # wrapping the two results in a list.
  f  # Flatten (convert decimal string into list of digits)
  b  # Convert to binary (as a list of digits, which will all be negative if the
     # number is negative)
3e   # Cube (applied to each digit)
Ṡ    # Vectorized Sum (apply individually to each list)
2c   # Does the resulting list (of two items) contain the number 2?
```

Alternatively instead of `3e` to cube each digit, `ʀṠ` could be used to triangularize each digit, or `√√` to take the fourth root of each digit.

If not for the fact that the challenge requires that negative numbers be tested (and that they can't be Two Bit Numbers™), this could be 7 bytes, because we could use `²` to square instead of `3e` to cube.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
∆b"vs⌊11c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLDt+G5oShuzrsiLCLiiIZiXCJ2c+KMijExYyIsIjvigKBbbixdKSIsIlstMzIsMjU2XSJd)
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiGYlwidnPijIoxMWMiLCIiLCIzXG45XG4xOFxuMTkyXG4yODhcbjUyMFxuNTI0MzA0XG4xMVxuMTAxXG4xMDAxXG4xMDEwXG4xMTAwXG4xMDAwMDAxXG4xMTAwMDAwMDAwXG4xMDAwMDAwMDEwXG4wXG4xXG4xMTJcbjIwMFxuNjQ5XG4tMVxuLTMiXQ==) - test cases only

```
∆b   # Convert to binary as a string.
"    # Pair that string and the original number as two items in a list.
vs   # Vectorized Sort - sort each individual item in the list (sorts the digits)
⌊    # Floor - in this context, used to interpret strings as decimal and convert
     # them to integers.
11c  # Does the resulting list (of two items) contain the number 11?
```

This solution was unusable at the time of my original posting, due to `⌊` not working on `0`. The bug has since been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
0&<*10&#.inv+&(2=1#.*~)#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7LDoJADLzzFRNJgEXZtN2lPCInE0@e/AUjEQ9688ivY40Sm/Qxzcy092Xj8xFDjxw7EHrLyuNwPh0XyvYlU5b66fHaZoUMnPpydmm/uOR6uT0xgpl@sW5qiYHiFxVFOmPckMPkIbU6VD0Caig6MJkaLOAG3EIIEhECglVFJMQWalSFtmgELaFTU/HnqOnMIVgPZmB8jhGshjtJ/s/JOmrsljc)

#### How it works

```
0&<*10&#.inv+&(2=1#.*.~)#:
0&<*                       input is a positive number
    10&#.inv               list of digits base 10
                        #: list of digits base 2
            +&(        )   OR the result of both …
                    *.~    square each digit (x>=2 will be larger than 2)
                 1#.       sum
               2=          is equal to two
```

If there is a DecimalBinary number, the `+` as OR could result in 2, thus needing one byte more for `+.`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>There's gotta be a way to shave at least one more byte off this.</s>
I got there eventually!

```
ìÍ-B©a¢ñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=7M0tQqlhovE&input=Mw) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7M0tQqlhovE&footer=VmdX%2bSkrIiA9ICIrIVU&input=WwozLDksMTgsMTkyLDI4OCw1MjAsNTI0MzA0CjExLDEwMSwxMDAxLDEwMTAsMTEwMCwxMDAwMDAxLDExMDAwMDAwMDAsMTAwMDAwMDAxMAowLDEsMTEyLDIwMCw2NDksLTEsLTMKXS1tUg)

```
ìÍ-B©a¢ñ     :Implicit input of integer U
ì            :Convert to digit array
 Í           :Sort (and implicitly convert back to integer)
  -B         :Subtract 11
    ©        :Logical AND with
     a       :Absolute difference of B and
      ¢      :Convert U to binary string
       ñ     :Sort
             :Implicit output of logical NOT of result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{$_|.base(2)~~/^10*10*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzdCsIwDIXv8xS5KKKOuaSto70Q38QxoQVh/rBejelevaYThJyQ851DXmEc2nyfcBPxhHlW3ftw7VPY6t2yNBemvYxqPjn1E54jVqrD@BxxuD1CygY8sAP2GrRzcNQksoYsMANT0bqYBBAVSyv5HfRHVCpiJJFXglvroWaozRc)

Checks if the input or the base 2 of the input matches the regex `^10*10*$`

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 1.3](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>61</s> <s>57</s></sup> 50 bytes

using a regex on the binary and decimal representation of the number

```julia
!x=count(r"^0*10*10*$",x)>0
~x=!"$x"|!bitstring(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFNa4NAEIbv/oqJycEtfuwmaUksBlropZQemkMPIYVVN2rYrKJraqHkr9tZbQjoOPO878zs4rGVBWddPwWepiKFQsGrQcD8hTWFXOuqCYMgK3Texn5SnoJBfuMqC44mC2JZxsEZ7T4N3l8@t/4pnSrx7ckirnn94x1aleiiVI31zBuBI1qlnYprLWoVhh8iE50Lja4LlYXhU4wZT/R2qB@hPIta8io6cNkIEkmhMp07SSmlSLQjeJKfuE7y67zroFvj/5cQ0k@6aFxe21/0jg3PzHY7sqHWpYsm9qyzfydxoccZTkd6LRrdQAQ7C2C3cGHtAlvhu567MF9hdj@nJiwXdLl3jYkxlOkQxsjQwLAYCB3hmNEbREzHfoOMwyww@sMSd3qIvIXBDF17yzqUNWR12Vbmfw2HxF4DTW7YICIDqPAuWirHKC7YEG3AduEy1ISgRajUutmIhXX/Bw)

Comment: Nice first post!

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>79</s> <s>74</s> 70 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to chunes

```
: n ( n -- ? ) dup present swap >bin [ 48 swap remove "11"= ] bi@ or ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LTsMwELz3K0Y9wcFV1jZukoqHuKBccimcEAenGDWCOMF2qFDFt6cbkJB62MeMZmb3ze5SH6anbVU/lHh3wbsPdDbtV4MN0QVE9zk6v3MRQ3DR@TTPlL6H0PK@WVR1iSqKtLdJ@LFrXBBWPB56cd8mUf8SUwmPCy4hcItLvI7Df1g82AE3TevxDJ3/weC6/sthSbS8xgua9g59wGY6QuEKBgUoAxFIgtagHDKD1FAKiruBzuYow1IDk2MtkWcoDLvYM1slJyieigNYT1qDDONC4of/8Hy04z9WWBzBNJsk38hgdAFBEOpcNp0A)

Comment: You can save a byte with `present` instead of `10 >base`, save 2 bytes with `dup present swap >bin` instead of `[ present ] [ >bin ] bi`, and save another byte by removing the space after the string.

Comment: @chunes Thank you! I wasn't aware of `present`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>71</s> 64 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen

```r
`+`=function(n,k)sum((n%/%k^(0:n)%%k)^2)-2
n=scan();n<0|n+2&n+10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7wTatNC@5JDM/TyNPJ1uzuDRXQyNPVV81O07DwCpPU1U1WzPOSFPXiCvPtjg5MU9D0zrPxqAmT9tILU/b0OC/ocV/AA)

Output is reversed: gives `FALSE` if the input is a Two Bit Number, and `TRUE` if it is not.

The helper function `+` converts an integer to a vector of digits in base `k` (we need `k=2` and `k=10`). Then sum the square of these digits. This sum is equal to 2 exactly for a Two Bit Number.

Will fail due to memory limits for large input, in which case you can use `0:log2(n)` instead of `0:n` and `||` instead of `|`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQffcwZrBIXUXlVcQQirC@kLnz7vbe25qX3h4F4bsSCEPkXB4iiElER2q502kIzEJEdoZH08HmsIN4xaZqhTQ9pFZNz@0H).

Comment: This seems to invert true and false... Not sure if that's usually allowed with IO rules.

Comment: @AJFaraday Yes, that is what I meant by "output is reversed". I took the challenge spec of "some indicator of true or false" as meaning that any 2 consistent values (here false and true) would be OK, but if that doesn't suit you I can correct it at the cost of 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: I've checked, this is typically allowed. Upvoted :)

Comment: @AJFaraday This is explicitly allowed by your own rules anyway, as _some indicator of true or false_  can definitely be _false and true_.

Comment: Nice.  -1 byte by using ```|``` instead of ```||```, and -6 more bytes by using ```n``` instead of ```log2(n)```, although I would understand that this is less desirable because it won't run any more in practice for large values of n (even though the approach is sound...).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! The main golf (`n` instead of `log2(n)`) works, but the `==1` trick fails for input `n=112`.

Comment: I knew there must've been a reason for the ```||``` instead of ```|```, I just couldn't think what it was...!

Comment: Actually `|` works now that the `log2` is out!

Comment: @RobinRyder Your approach is undoubtedly the more elegant, but somehow a [much clunkier one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211889/95126) seems to be a bit shorter...

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>21</s> 13 bytes

```
№⟦⁻θ0⁻⍘Ｎ²0⟧11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5vxRIRvtm5pUWaxTqKCgZKGnqKEC4TonFqcElQGXpGp55BaUlfqW5SalFGkB5I02IylggZWiopKlp/f@/kYHBf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a two bit number, nothing if not. Port of @Kaddath's PHP answer. Explanation:

```
   θ            Input as a string
  ⁻ 0           Remove zeros
       Ｎ        Input as a number
      ⍘ ²       Convert to base 2
     ⁻   0      Remove zeros
 ⟦        ⟧     Make into a list
№          11   Count occurances of literal string `11`
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda n:n>2in{g(n,2),g(n,10)}
g=lambda x,b:x and(x%b)**2+g(x//b,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RDoIwDEXf9xV9MWw64jbQKAn8CPLAgiCJDoKYYAjfji1ofFh3e@5t2vbd3xoXzGV8me/5wxY5uMglpnZjxZ00QtKnlZhYFX8Dg7TRALkr@LCxYrs1u4oP@72VVsz99dk/IYaUAaSBhLMEfcJ3NhLMCdXBKCphoMJMUkhrtNVS1qoxoLFZiFrhqtQfIlbrPCFK0ALyjyHu9BH5AQYyxsqmg6prXi3UDpb7IpwjSg3BxSUI0Ha163npjeRN4Ccwlpy0mDzBfr6YPw)

Port of my Haskell answer. (I took the test harness from ovs's Python answer. Thanks!)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lp`, 35 bytes

```perl
$_=grep/^10*10*$/,$_,sprintf"%b",$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCoMwDEXf8xnSvQyLN20d7cN@ZYLghiAaqt@/LnUg5IackxCZ8tKXYobnJ0/SvRh3LdO1Zmh3yfN6vJvb2CiW4ikRR@LkyMVIvYMmeARiJkbN2RgqgIo4zX/ApVBPFHSjr1Q/QiLLZP13k2Pe1r3YRX4)

returns 1 or 2 (if a number can be decimal and binary Two Bit number) for true, 0 for false.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby 2.7, 44 bytes

```ruby
->n{[2,10].any?{n.to_s(_1).tr(?0,'')=='11'}}
```

**Explanation:**

```ruby
->n{                      # a lambda with one argument
    [2,10].any?{          # Return true if for either of 2 or 10...
      n.to_s(_1)          # input in that base
      .tr(?0,'')          # after removing all 0-s
      =='11'              # is exactly '11'
    }
}
```

### Equivalent in ruby < 2.7, 46 bytes

```ruby
->n{[2,10].any?{|b|n.to_s(b).tr(?0,'')=='11'}}
```

[Try it out](https://tio.run/##XZC7DoMgFIZ3n4JOaKLkHLRGBuuDENKUwcnYxstg1GenpAiaTv93/styhlkvpiW1yR79KnmKoNirX5p101vPpvdzjHXCpiFuIKU0qWuKSPfdfOZpJDIipJW5Sn8qDsXKg@AH8cp7dw6BihwKe7gu@hGcdEH0M7T2WYBLx53wF4ObWufWShdZwADIPXIIcVkIj1moZrmK7HO6rjFf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 36 bytes

```
^\d+
$*1¶$&
+`^(1+)\1
$+0
m`^10*10*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCgIxFEP3OUcdxikDSVulPYGXGEoHdOFCF@LZPIAXq79CEpIHed3e9@feD/Ol9bpdPdyi78dN8K3O8sdNcJ54tCouJtd7RIEyVAJCzjgFmlNkggRx@B@iAXJMDmLNgJ2MnVPBKqzxBw) Link includes most test cases (the larger ones cause Retina to run out of memory). Explanation:

```
^\d+
$*1¶$&
```

If the input is non-negative, prefix it with a unary copy.

```
+`^(1+)\1
$+0
```

Begin converting the unary copy to binary. At this point there are too many zeros in the result, but fortunately they are irrelevant.

```
m`^10*10*$
```

Match either number as being a two bit number.

Answer (score 4):

## [MUMPS](http://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Eokane/), 55 bytes

```
 i $tr(n,01) f  q:n<1  s %=n#2_%,n=n\2
 w $tr(n_%,0)=11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZI/D4IwEMV3PsVZNYGEJm1BA0YW4goTo4lBxaSJFPkX4qfHAgvDYejQ4ffeXd71mrf5p@6hAxJKlVZfSLqChrIBM4ksiNv8nlU1MbRhA0@QtZa1mkSmYyHQxyD3UOoLDAsPdR8Ew7HrMHdShotcsofM0/fqKThHs7EFvMC1sOBnf0qms1yoS9lstLhQdO1YeFc8CL4GPNjRRTdM0dZ0@CKlMSNKgxr2ASE9SNg1lals/T7wAihP6sxhVNVW3Pa2CtRVDF1HmwbMCjjvoex/)

- Each line has a leading space so that the commands aren't interpreted as line labels.
- `$tr` is short for `$translate` which replaces one or more characters in a string with one or more other characters. For example, `$tr("abc","a","c")` evaluates to `"cbc"`. Omitting the third parameter is the same as passing the empty string, in which case the characters in the second parameter are removed. Therefore `$tr(n,01)` is nonempty only if it contains any characters other than 0 or 1, and `$tr(n,0)` removes all zeroes from the string.
- `i` is short for `if`, its condition is the following `$tr(n,01)` expression. The condition is only met if `n` needs to be converted to binary.
- `f` is short for `for` and loops until the `quit` condition (`q:n<0`) becomes true. The loop converts `n` to binary in `%`.
- `w` is short for `write` and prints the expression that follows it.
- If the `for` loop was executed then `n` will be empty or zero, otherwise `%` will be empty. `n_%` concatenates the two so that the result can be evaluated in a single expression.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn

```
{("11"~($x)^$0)+2=+/2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxLCsJAEAX3nuIRAkkIg9MfOzOCNxGX40LIOiB69fG56UdDVb3S/tx7b9f3PIgM33k8lseYl1Vv61nvx6e3yXBBoEIyRCAK2SAFmqEOMxhvwDO8IIgGomBTlIwatOj8VWXBuMYAeXGHBP@qpzZxSSmjGeEVSZAM/Qc)

Comment: `"0"` ---> `$0`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
,BṢ€Ḍ11e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/H6eHORY@a1jzc0WNomPr/cDuQDUT//0cb6yhY6igYWgCxpZGOgpEFkGVqZAAiTIwNTGJ1FKINDYGSBmACQhoCpQ2BHLCIAUQQwjJACAKFDUC6QQIgeZDhIFkzE6B9ukAhXeNYAA)

### Explanation

```
,BṢ€Ḍ11e  Main Link
,         Pair the integer with
 B        Convert the integer to binary
  Ṣ€      Sort Each (sorts the digits of the integer implicitly)
    Ḍ     Convert from decimal to integer
     11e  Is 11 in this list?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
!FreeQ[Tr/@(#~IntegerDigits~{10,2}^2),2]&&#>0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBC8IwDIX/ijIYChlL0intQdlBBG8K3kRhjFJ72A61t7H99RqnBl7Il/eSrolP2zXRt01yu7Q8Bmsvt2so61U2nfponQ0H73x8TQMh8PjgNfA9z7M95ukcfB8XZe3KelBggDSQYWCtYcMoqhRWQASEIrknxBnwQzMifq1fwX@SiIA48k7WSrStDBQEhZJOY0pv)

*-1 byte from @att*

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##NYxBC8IwDIX/ijIYChlL0intQdlBBG8K3kRhjFJ72A61t7H99RqnBl7Il/eSrolP2zXRt01yu7Q8Bmsvt2so61U2nfponQ0H73x8TQMh8PjgNfA9z7M95ukcfB8XZe3KelBggDSQYWCtYcMoqhRWQASEIrknxBnwQzMifq1fwX@SiIA48k7WSrStDBQEhZJOY0pv) since infix has higher precedence than `Power`

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>73</s> <s>63</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```scala
n=>Seq(n+"",n.toBinaryString)find(_ matches "10*"*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5NS8NAEIbv/RVDTkm1ZXcTpRFSUPTgRQ/1JiLbZNSVZhKz40cRf3sMFjTKjtfnmfd9x5d2Y/tm/Yglw9Vrc@L44rleY@cB3xip8nDctvA@ebEbsEdwTgzFEi5bdg1dr7hzdH8DRU/FcoVPMe1F0T7Neegh2213PrlzVMW3UFsuH9BDpNU0mpqkt95jx7GN02Tu/CkOd1glk2@ch7FeCDw3YWEWQuLAKElkqcp@udGOFvaVKGSjhQ/0EBLblFy4s@r/sPo7@3Pwxc/qlrfjVBBqE8JGBSsOszyEZ8HqWTqiH/0n)

**Edit:**

- Thanks to @Tomer Shetah for pointing out that lamdbas do not require their type definition (see comments), which reduces the length from 73 to 63 bytes
- Thanks to @user for adding some nice syntax tricks that further reduce the length from 63 to 54 bytes
- Again thanks to @user for the comment on using `find` instead of `exists`, which saves another 2 bytes and is valid for this challenge, since it is stated that a valid solution should *"output true or false (or some indicator of true or false)"*

Comment: You can do it in -10 bytes. [Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bX2KdTmVRhiLEOmrgIhQJQ)

Comment: I am unsure about whether it is accepted for a Scala solution to provide an anonymous expression that cannot be called without binding it to some function name and signature to make it actually callable.
You exclude the `val f: Int => Boolean =` from your byte-counts, although it is required to call the expression. I include the binding via the (shorter) `def a(n:Int)=` alternative.
So my question in a nutshell: is for example `_.length` a valid solution, or only one of `val a: String => Int = _.length` or `def a(s: String)=s.length` ?
Perhaps this is a topic for a meta discussion.

Comment: It has already been discussed. Please read [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/98669)

Comment: You can get [54](https://tio.run/##bdAxb8IwEAXgnV9xzeQAQbYJiCAFqWxdWOheHekJgoIT4mtLhfjtIRVqlYs6fuf33mCfYYFNuTtSxvD6Va5z3nycdlR7oAuTe/fwXFVwHXxiAbiEF8eQrmBdlgWhg7Rx6WpLZ@VGQTB2E24HHNbfW65ztw/pknv26g1OyNmBPARGD4OhDRv0nmpWqKZhOPhD0oVZCCW2S7sQrzOrJeOpjttLp2/Emu6xbyP2TBvo5XW/8rjp/4L6Mfd7fkLVCbUyUsYKWy3T8zgRjmQ9@vnRW3MH) bytes. In fact, if you use `find` instead of `exists`, you can save 2 bytes more, but you'll have to change your test cases to use `!=None` instead.

Comment: -1 for being spherical lettuce and calling yourself cubic lettuce

Answer (score 3):

### PCRE Regex, <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```
^(((?(2)\2\2|.))*.)(?!\1)((?(3)\3\3|.))*.$|^(((?(5)\5{10}|.{9}))*.)(?!\4)((?(6)\6{10}|.{9}))*.$
```

Assume unary input (no support for negative numbers).

Should work in flavors with support for conditional regex and forward-declared back-reference.

The regex consists of 2 similar portions, one check for binary and the other for decimal.

- The code makes use of sum of geometric series to match 2<sup>n</sup> and 10<sup>n</sup>.
  1 + (1 + 2 + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>n</sup>) = 2<sup>n+1</sup>
  1 + 9 * (1 + 10 + 10<sup>2</sup> + ... + 10<sup>n</sup>) = 10<sup>n+1</sup>
- Then it try to decompose the number into sum of 2<sup>n</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> (or 10<sup>n</sup> + 10<sup>k</sup> for decimal), and check that 2<sup>n</sup> != 2<sup>k</sup>

Update:

- Drops unused capturing group
- Drops `$` in `(?!\1$)` since it's fine if we reject 2<sup>n</sup> < 2<sup>k</sup>

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Eyz3Se/2)

Comment: I really did not expect a regex answer to this :)

Comment: This inelegant regex works in ecma: `^((x)+|(x)+)(((\2+)\3+)\6{8}(?=\5$))+(?=(((\2+)\3+)\9{8}(?=\8$))*x$)\1$`. Ideally the choice distinction 2 and 10 would be more subtle.

Comment: @H.PWiz Post your own answer :)

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what the regex is about - it decomposes number n into a * (1 + 2^b) then check a = 2^k. And the capturing group 2 and 3 switches between base 2 and base 10.

Comment: Is there any reason not to do [this](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkRCTos2lovU/TgMIDLU1NextY0xUNDW1a@I0DTWrjWpVamBSMRbVFrUgeQsU@f//jbksuQwtuAwtjbiMLCy4TI0MuAwNuQwNQBhMGIIEDAy4gBSQAVQFZJuZWHLpGnLpGgMA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")?

Comment: @Neil: I still haven't learned Retina, unfortunately.

Comment: I was only using Retina for demonstration purposes, as a program of just one regex is treated as a decision problem (technically a match count) and you can use the header to format human-readable input. The interesting bit is just the test for the sum of two distinct powers of the same base.

Comment: @Neil: I think it's a better solution - please go ahead and make your own answer. I don't understand why people keep commenting on my answer while their comment has a good answer with different approach to the problem

Answer (score 3):

## Generic regex, <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
^(((1+)(?=\3$))+1|^1){2}$|^(((1+)\6{8}(?=\6$))+1|^1){2}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYq9CsMgHMT3ew4DfysBTxvRofRFJDSQDl06lG6Jz261ZMlwH9zvPs/v673UQR55NVCXOosIjZb7LXulteE@U2@uqP0gOWyxdBxOuFaPBEYwObgYMTkLErRdf2MfrEWLVtqr9XBNGInR/wA) Link includes test harness written in [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) although the regex itself should work in most engines. Takes input in signed unary i.e. `^-?1*$`. Explanation: Given `k` and `m` we can write a specific test for a number being the sum of `k` distinct powers of `m` by repeatedly dividing by `m` and subtracting `1` `k` distinct times along the way, before we eventually reach zero:

```
^(((1+)\3{<m-2>}(?=\3$))+1|^1){<k>}$
```

where `<m-2>` and `<k>` represent substitutions for the specific values being tested (subject to trivial reductions such as `\3{0}` being a no-op). This works as follows:

```
   (1+)                                 Find `i` such that
       \4{<m-2>}                        `i+(m-2)i=(m-1)i` is equal to
                (?=\4$)                 `n-i`, therefore `i=n/m`.
  (                    )+               Divide `n` by `m` at least once
                         1              Then decrement
 (                        |^1)          Or on the first loop just decrement
                              {<k>}     Decrement `k` distinct times
^                                  $    Consume entire input
```

The problem then reduces to an alternation of two such tests. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by noticing from @Deadcode's answer that `(((...)+|^)1)` is the same as `((...)+1|^1)`.

Comment: I'm very impressed by your generic regex's shortness! Here is a [ECMAScript test harness](https://tinyurl.com/4yuapdes) for it. I have been trying to construct a similarly short generic or ECMAScript regex without reading yours, and so far have not been able to do better than [70 generic](https://tinyurl.com/4mxprmkb), [68 ECMAScript](https://tinyurl.com/zyxrpp9j), or [54 with molecular lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/fR8jhC/1/). I'm finding it extremely hard to combine the binary and decimal tests compactly without molecular lookahead or variable-length lookbehind, but I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
#2§¤eṁ^3ḋd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aElq7qOmxv/KRoeWA9kPdzbGGT/c0Z3y////aGMdSx1DCx1DSyMdIwsLHVMjAyA2MTYw0TE01DE0AGEwYWgAFDAwAHENwCIQhgFcCChoEPs/GsgFygENA0qYmVjq6Brq6BoDSQPDWAA)

#### Explanation

```
  §            Apply to input the two functions
         d       Convert to list of digits
        ḋ        And convert to list of binary digits
   ¤e          Then apply to both values
     ṁ^3         Cube each and sum
#2             How many 2s are there in the list?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

```perl
sub($n){$_=sprintf"=$n=%b=",$n;s/0//g;/=11=/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/RisMgEHzvVyxiSkINapIebYNcf6B/cFDSnpZAMcE1T@V@/Tw1Dz3BYXZ2lt2ZtXvuAzUq4HIrqa1e9KpwdqP1hihqVXFThFHbIxecP3qupFT8J/Rw9hr9fUCNoKDcQHwtgyMDeYj/2DBoDpHtG5Gga0XHsknK2BYZVpTRIGORFbGKKxNvUSRbnk9ScqQFqf/RxZ11lOq26jfxYnplsAYAUkj5fYICvyxhQC2DcktNigmfQLxbNIETEDM8UZMKzOT@xQq/0@zHyWKoL0YPfnF6h@PDZoZ/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 35 bytes

```perl
$_.=sprintf" %b",$_;$_=/\b10*10*\b/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXs@2uKAoM68kTUlBNUlJRyXeWiXeVj8mydBAC4hikvT//7f8l19QkpmfV/xft@C/rq@pnoGhAQA)

Comment: Nice, I tried to shrink down [@Donat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222881/9365) but just ended up with [@NahuelFouilleul's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211869/9365). Assuming the input ends in a newline (default for `<<<`) you can save 1 byte omitting the space: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXs@2uKAoM68kTUk1SUlHJd5aJd5WPybJ0EALiGKS9P//t@T6l19QkpmfV/xft@C/rq@pnoGhAQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: I thought I had a solution in 32 bytes, but it doesn't support binary numbers > 255, so close: [Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89L14xMCoxMCokL3wyPT11bnBhY2tcIiVCKlwiLGNociIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xMVxuMTJcbjEwMDEwMDEwXG4xMTAwMDAwMFxuMTAwMDEwMDAifQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig) < 1.0.0, \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
Gu=11Oeo0wb
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

I will not let Vyxal beat me. Even though I ported it. No. Never. That thing that beat me by 0.054 bytes is not Vyxal. It is an impostor. Long live Fig!!!

```
Gu=11Oeo0wb # Takes 1 input
          b # Convert to binary
         w  # Wrap it in a list with the original number
      eo0   # Remove 0s
     O      # Join by nothing
  =11       # Equal to 11?
 u          # Unpack the list into the arguments of...
G           # Max
```

Comment: So I haven't been able to run this, but based on your explanation it looks like it always converts to binary. Can this still detect decimal two-bit numbers? Also, does it handle the negative and "two or more" cases?

Comment: @AJFaraday see the `w` operator: "Wrap it in a list **with the original number**". And yes it has the same behavior as Vyxal.

Comment: [you've been beaten by 1.054 bytes >.<](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250410/92689)

Comment: @Steffan noooooooo. time to port.

Comment: Do you not have a contains builtin? Not even a digraph? Even a digraph would save 1 UTF-8 byte

Comment: @Steffan oh yeah i do...

Comment: When you realize checking if any are equal is the same as contains

Answer (score 3):

## [Chocolate](https://github.com/Steffan153/chocolate), 8 bytes

```
ċ11€ṛ0;B
```

[Try it online!](https://chocolate-lang.netlify.app/#WyLOs8SLMTHigqzhuZswO0IiLCJbMywgOSwgMTgsIDE5MiwgMjg4LCA1MjAsIDUyNDMwNCwgMTEsIDEwMSwgMTAwMSwgMTAxMCwgMTEwMCwgMTAwMDAwMSwgMTEwMDAwMDAwMCwgMTAwMDAwMDAxMCwgMCwgMSwgMTEyLCAyMDAsIDY0OSwgLTEsIC0zXSJd)

Link includes `γ` (map) for test cases.

```
ċ11€ṛ0;B
       B ## Binary representation (as a string) of the input
      ;  ## Make a list with that and the input
   €ṛ0   ## For each, remove all zeros
ċ11      ## Does this contain 11? (11 == "11")
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 46 bytes

```
n->(d=digits(n))*d~==2||sumdigits(n,2)==2&&n>0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY7PCsIwDMZfJewgq7SSdVO2Q_ciIjIYGwUtZX8OwvBF9DAQ8Zl8G5NV8ZAvX35J09xevurssfXzowHzHIdG5e-NU2Vcm9q2duhjJ8S6vhqjp6kfzz8otSC0WrkSv6_ulfenS-xAleA76wayERcRNLxEwj6VUEhIcopCS9A5ua1GlizFjHBCgYsETZAh4kIwwODwD3EZ45K7vJh7u4z-UoRUehDhxnkO-QM)

For base 2, checks whether the sum of the digits is \$2\$.

For base 10, checks whether the sum of the squares of the digits is \$2\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
11N[TBaa]DC0
```

Outputs 1 for two-bit numbers, 0 otherwise. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIjExTltUQmFhXURDMCIsIiIsIiIsIjI1OCJd) Or, [use as a filter to get all two-bit numbers up to 101](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIntcbjExTltUQmFhXURDMFxufSBGSSAtMTEgXFwsIDEwMSIsIiIsIiIsIi1wIl0=).

#### Explanation

```
   [    ]     Construct a list containing
    TBa         the input converted to binary
       a        and the input unchanged
         DC0  Delete all occurrences of the character 0 from both
11N           Count how many times 11 occurs in the resulting list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>22</s> 16 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

```
}11,v-Q\0v-.BQ\0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9bQUKdMNzDGoExXzwlI/f9vaGgAAA)

Comment: You can save some bytes by using `-` to remove zeros (it will automatically convert to string) and using `}` to test on a list rather than doing two equality comparisons.

Comment: 14 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzYhI0RHNzDGQFfPKdDg/39DQwMA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```php
echo($f=fn($s)=>str_replace(0,'',$s)==11)($argn)|$f(decbin($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxRC4JAEITf91eIHHgHCrtqopn11q8IwuxMIc5D7a3fnu1p9DDDzjfL2M4uh5Nl1003SNFWrZFiUtVxmsfrqO2zbrTEMAhCRysiJUU9Pox6i1bedXPrzQ@oct3wfE/2xr7mvbfxi/HLJYECKAcqYojzHHYxstIEUyACQqfVCBkguogr2Q78I3QvHLjhKcZZWkBEECWfwc79YKYlOn8B)

Pretty straightforward: treats each input as a string, replaces all zeroes by `''` and tests if it (loosely) equals `11`, or if the binary does

EDIT: saved 2 bytes by using `0` instead of `'0'`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>75</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>76</s></sup> 80 bytes

Added 6 bytes to fix a bug.

```c
d;r;c;f(n){for(c=2,r=__builtin_popcount(n)!=2|n<0;n>0;n/=10)d=n%10,c-=d*d;r*=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHbboMwDH3nKzykSkCDCuHSopC@TPuKtUJtgA1pDRVQrVrHtzMH6AabtEhW7GOfE9sR9osQXZeyigmWG9K85WVlCE5JxZPkeCnemkIm5/IsyotsMP/A6aeMHSa3aCvuOmbK5cJ1iLB5aqGOxQVru0I2cDoU0jC1mwZ4FNC8l8mxaBJ5OdXPe@Bw8wgEBEICEQHUANdFo2hrtA0Bihj1CXhY6KkbS33EfMyFiolxiP4aORvEo1DpKJFejSpZT3meElVs10cZN1RYRFvW9yZeD5UF1dCSvrs@0d01ekQLdALT2NOR0VNwS2D0M2U1DoREmwYBu4cx0CBksFwOsQnDEu6LqLE@N8Ycm6VEWVWZaLCghgcOzk/2@8lCptkVVG50Y6iLj6xExcmCzdUIWjNUNdWzpj31j@dg3Ifh86/q6/e/Cf3mJt3yWbfqtNpfb/JMDI75z7znCofNDX3hp2BvQV2LeifxSwY@gZrgp40C@3GPrdZ2Xw)

Returns a falsy value if \$n\$ is a Two Bit Number™️ or a truthy one otherwise.

Comment: strictly speaking `__builtin_popcount` is a built-in function that only exists in some compilers and not a standard function

Comment: @phuclv true, but, "For the purposes of PPCG, a programming language is defined by its implementation." https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/43195

Comment: @phuclv As it clearly states my answer is for **GCC**, `__builtin_popcount` is a [GCC builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVHbboMwDH3nKzykVkCDSsKlRSF9mfYVa1V1KWw8NEyBadU6vp05lG6wSUMysY99TmxH@s9Sdp3mkheOci9FpR0pGNFCzZVP8dQZ/dRz7VOuNgFXS0EDV/pCzWjgOebvcu0JyduuVA2cDqVyXOtiAX4GaN6r/VPZ7NXbqX7cgYBLSCAmkBBICdAAjaIxtBXamgBDjEUEQiwMzYmlEWIR5hLDxDhBf4WcNeJpYnSMSK/GjGxovNCIGjaNUIYmBktZy/ve5MtBe6CvLdnb8wPbntN7tNgmMI5DGxk9BXcDTj9TXuNASPRZHPNbmAGLEw6LxTV24bqE2yJqrC@cIccnKVlpncsGC2q4ExD8ZL@vLNUxP4PJDW4GdfmRV6g4WrC7HEBvgpqmeta4p/7yApzbMGL6VH397jeh39yoWzHp1nyt9dcbXZNB4P4z76vGYQvHnkVH8Ddgjlm9VfgkVz6BmuCjDQK7YY@t1XZf)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 19 bytes

```apl
2∊2 10(+.×⍨⊤)¨⊢×0<⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R2wSjRx1dRgqGBhraeoenP@pd8ahrieYhILno8HQDGyD1/1HfVKCytEMrFIwVLBUMLRQMLY0UjCwsFEyNDIDYxNjAhAuhxtAQaBYIgwlDA6CAgQGIawAWgTAM4EJAQQMk3UBhoBqg8UAFZiaWCofWGwKx8X8A)

**Commented:**

```apl
                0<⊢  ⍝ Is the (right) argument greater than 0
              ⊢×     ⍝ Multiply this with the argument
                     ⍝   results in 0 for negative inputs
  2 10(     )¨       ⍝ Call the next function with each of the bases 2 and 10
                     ⍝   and the non-negative number as a right argument
           ⊤         ⍝ Convert number to base digits
       +.×⍨          ⍝ The sum of squares of the digits
2∊                   ⍝ Does this contain 2?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17  14</s>  12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
[¢Us]d_e0 ¥B
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=W6JVc11kX2UwIKVC&input=MTAx)

```
[¢Us]         - input to string base 2 , 10
     d_       - if any :
          ¥B  - are == 11 after 
       e0     - removing 0
```

- Saved 3 stealing from @ovs Python answer, upvote him!

Comment: [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=W1XszVXsZl34Qg&input=MTAx)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 67 bytes

```java
n->(" "+n+" "+n.toString(n,2)+" ").replace("0","").contains(" 11 ")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVA7b8IwEN75FSdPtuJEdpKiBNQunTqUhRExGGNQaLCj2FBVKL89vTzo2JPu7O8e3z0u6q7iy/Gr17XyHj5VZR8LgMoG056UNrAZIMDBudooC5p@YOhsWrBsjZFugcYHFSoNG7Dw2tv4jRIgkY1GmwS3DW1lz9TylA0@lrSmqZGbEkE4QaydDdjYY52UmNCvB9bmdqiRdSa/u@oIV8yiE91uD4pNs51cS3FgCMaHd@UNrMCa72GH3f6R8ZLLgssy5WlR8JdUoOaZyLmUXApUKfAVIxADGqEQU2gW/vxhytjzX8F0rMWGWJihLvOSx5LHGVrZsZlg@@ODuSbuFpIGNwq1pc8NIrIab6f/PGy@dtf/Ag)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                       // Method with Integer parameter and boolean return-type
  (" "                    //  Have a leading space
   +n                     //  Appended with the input
   +" "                   //  Appended with another space
   +n.toString(n,2)       //  Appended with the input as binary-String
   +" ")                  //  Appended with a trailing space
        .replace("0","")  //  Then remove all "0"s from this string
        .contains(" 11 ") //  Check if what remains contains 11 surrounded with spaces
```

Comment: Surely `n.toString(2)` suffices?

Comment: @Neil No, I'm afraid not. The first `n` is used as a static call. Non-golfed, it would be `Integer.toString(n,2)`, which is a shorter variant of `Integer.toBinaryString(n)`. What you suggest is short for `Integer.toString(2)`, which would result in `"2"`, since the `Integer.toString(int)` method will use base-10 by default.

Comment: Ah, I thought there would be a non-static `toString(radix)` method for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 79 Bytes

```python
lambda n:any(sum((ord(c)-48)**4 for c in f.format(n))==2for f in["{}","{0:b}"])
```

### Explanation

I format the int as both binary and decimal. For each character, I subtract the `'0'` character, then raise it to the power of 4. This maps `'0'` to 0, `'1'` to 1, `'2'` to 16, and other digits and the `'-'` character to numbers greater than 16. Then, I check if the summation equals 2.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 93 bytes

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false

```sql
DECLARE @y INT=@,@x INT=9WHILE @>0SELECT
@x+=@%2,@/=2PRINT
IIF(11in(@x,replace(@y,0,'')),1,0)
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1305798/is-that-number-a-two-bit-number)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>67</s> 64 bytes

```matlab
@(x,p=@(b,z=dec2base(x*(x>0),b)-48)all(z<2)&sum(z)==2)p(2)|p(10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5dC4IwGIXv/RW7Md83pujIiGoh/YYuu/Fjg4HO4bRE@u9rWR04N8/hgdPXY/kQTvIkSVwBMzW8gIouvBE1q0orYN7CfEmRVhjvDli2LSxnhhs7dbAg5wwNMHwZyFJ0sh@InjrCSZwdWb4PiI@yt2d/VaOnEvyKpy@WBP4TruQTaQalRwlR2JDQ3nVEvUHXM0qv9k8Xugl83Rs)

If in doubt, make the code more convoluted. Somehow that tends to save bytes...

```matlab
@(x,                               % Main anonymous function with 'x' as input
    p=                             % Second input 'p' with default value (no second input is given when calling function) which
      @(b,                         % consists of another anonymous function which takes base as input
          z=                       % From which it creates a second input 'z' with default value
            dec2base(       ,b)    % Which runs dec2base (convert from integer to string) using provided base
                     x             % On the input to the main anonymous function
                      *(x>0)       % Multiplied by (x>0) to return false for any negative integer passed in.
                               -48 % And converts from a string to an array of integers (one per digit)
      )
      all(z<2)&                    % Two-bit numbers must only contain 0 or 1, so need all elements in array of digits <2.
               sum(z)==2           % Sum all digits. Two-digit number if sum is 2 (two 1's)
)
p(2))||                            % Run two-bit number check in base 2
       p(10)                       % Run two-bit number check in base 10
```

---

First attempt,

```matlab
@(x,p=@(z)all(z<50)&&sum(z-48)==2)x>0&&p(dec2bin(x))||p(num2str(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwEEX3nKIbykwCBBsxRq0hnsGlGwSaNIHS0KKEcPdaVH4yi/9mXqavbPlqnOBpmroCpljzAmYs2xbmS54hpWbsYE72R@Sc4XTNKNVQNxV7SgUT4rJoUGPHjB3W6kQ/EN8JJ8nuxPJDQHykub/7m7SeivUazz8sCGwr/JI1Qg9SWQFRWJPQPFQUeyPeXq72X29UHfhxHw)

```matlab
@(x,                               % Main anonymous function with 'x' as input
    p=                             % Second input 'p' with default value (no second input is given when calling function)
      @(z)                         % Default value consists of another anonymous function to check if string is two-bit
          all(z<50)&&              % Two-bit numbers must only contain '0' or '1', so need all elements in string <'2'(50).
                     sum(z-48)==2  % Convert all characters from '0'/'1' to 0/1 and sum. Two-digit if sum is 2 (two 1's)
)
x>0&&                              % Short-circuit to return false for any negative integer passed in.
     p(dec2bin(x))||               % Convert to binary string and check if two-digit, or...
                    p(num2str(x))  % Convert to decimal string and check if two-digit
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 157 bytes

```php
echo$argn>0&&(2==array_reduce(str_split($argn),fn($c,$i)=>$c+=$i?($i==1?1:9):0)||2==array_reduce(str_split(decbin($argn)),fn($c,$i)=>$c+=$i?($i==1?1:9):0));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU7LCsIwELzvVxQJkmALu22VPoy9@RWC1Fg1IGlI60Hw261pFW/iYYad2dlh7cUO68p6btSlZbU7mw3O5zyWsnauvu9dc7yphne923f2qns@ZUR4MpypkGkhN0wtJNMVZ1pKqqjIRYHi8fhdcWzUQZtP0/8qUcL0XTALuDb21hfB@3RnZuWQQA6UAeUxxFkGyxg90gRTIALCERMRegNxlDg57wG/Fo4RL/zGV3l7leYQEUTJs7W9bk03RNsX)

Comment: @Kaddath beats me by almost 100 bytes :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```groovy
f={1.bitCount(it)==2|it==~'10*'*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNT8MwDL3nV5jTPpJVy0ezVSJIgHaYBFxgXKYKDdSOXhqpMyA0xl8vNmxIsEZ6ifPy/Bx73cT4@t62Zdjq5LHCy/hSY7/CQQjmo8IQPnt6POwNza69LfB0XmOxLpozwLd4USEEWFoFqQKvIFOgxwRNMIQJYarAEGecAktCyydJHXGO3jxn0t1TPKGcKfGZZx82@XYzbGs5smzK2dqRjfbMZSYHKeDfWu6/mVzPbx7uz68WM5BAjl206aZdLv70W0e8O7TcH5nUJwltAxgdJiE7qkrbYS7TXIifpKSMzWz19AxbWG02RYNQ8uhhJ37LHUtO9pr2Cw)

Note that this treats negative numbers as 2-bit if its binary representation has exactly two 1 bits, e.g. `Integer.MIN_VALUE+1 == 10000000000000000000000000000001` would be 2-bit.

Comment: Reduced by one byte by replacing `'10*10*'` with `'10*'*2`

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 169 bytes

```
=LET(n,LEN(A1),e,SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,""),d,(n-LEN(e)=2)*(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(e,0,""))=0),b,CONCAT(DEC2BIN(MOD(INT(A1/512^{0,1,2}),512))),t,(LEN(b)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(b,1,"")))=2,d+t)
```

### Excel (future release), 166 bytes

```
=LET(s,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,"")),n,LEN(A1),e,s(A1,1),d,(n-LEN(e)=2)*(LEN(s(e,0))=0),b,CONCAT(DEC2BIN(MOD(INT(A1/512^{0,1,2}),512))),t,(LEN(b)-LEN(s(b,1)))=2,d+t)
```

This uses `LAMBDA` which isn't widely available yet.  Not much savings.

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.408 bytes

```
I11eo0wOb
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

Yeaa I [beat Vyxal!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250176/107299). Also took down Chocolate as well.

```
I11eo0wOb # Full program
        b # Convert the number to binary
       O  # Join the list of binary
      w   # Wrap it in a list with the original number
   eo0    # Remove 0s
I11       # Contains 11?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>12</s> <s>9</s> 12 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
⁼←±Î¡Oû¨¨K²$
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=WytcO2ItLTohMSNdJjI=&input=Mwo5CjE4CjE5MgoyODgKNTIwCjUyNDMwNAowCjEKMTEyCjIwMAo2NDkKLTEKLTMKMjAw)

### Old answer:

```
©ou…ö6úË»˜½$
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `[+\;b--:!1#]&2`

```
  [         Begin sequence
            ENTRY ONE
    +\        Fold with sum
        _     Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
      ;b      In binary
            ENTRY TWO
    --        Subtract one from
          _   Implied
        :!    Split on every
          1     
      #       Length
  ]         End sequence
&           Contains
  2         Literal two
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail on `-1` and `-3` now?

Comment: ah... yes, you are correct. I'll fix this later

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>9</s> 32 bytes

```
{({~#($x)^"1 0"} x)|{2=+/2\x} x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJzLsKrWqK5T1lCp0IxTMlQwUKpVqNCsqTay1dY3iqkAcmq5uPQVQopKSzIquTIUjIHYUgFIGFqASUsjIGlkYQEkTY0MwKSJsYEJSMoQRBhASChlaACWMDCACBpAxSFMAyRhA5BSfQW3xJzi1EqwErA9YBVmJpZAUhekU9cYAMtfKhM=)

Having to add more bytes because I read the challenge wrong. Doesn't work correctly with `0` and `1`. Return `1` for true, and `0` for false.

Explanation:

```
{({~#($x)^"1 0"} x)|{2=+/2\x} x}       Main program. x is input
                    {       }          Execute a function with argument x
                         2\x           Convert to base 2
                       +/              Sum
                     2=                Equals to 2
                   |                   Or
 ({            } x)                    Execute a function with argument x
          "1 0"                        String "1 0"
         ^                             Without (set function)
     ($x)                              Input converted to string
    #                                  Length
   ~                                   Not
```

Comment: It should return true for `11` as well, based on the definition of Two Bit Number™️

Comment: @mathjunkie It's supposed to return `1` for binary and `0` for decimal, so `11` is decimal (0). I have made the summary clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you've misunderstood the challenge. Binary *and* Decimal Two Bit Numbers should both return `true`, while Non Two Bit Numbers should return `false`. For example,  `9`, `11`, `18`, and `101` should all return the same value and `0`, `1`, and `112` should return a different value.

Comment: @mathjunkie Yeah, I probably get the challenge wrong, will fix it soon.