# Test whether a sequence is bitonic

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, decision-problem

You know what a *mono*tonic sequence is: each element is bigger than its predecessor (monotonically rising) or as its successor (monotonically falling).

*Bi*tonic means you have two arms of the sequence, one monotonically rising, the other falling.

For example, `1,3,5,7,6,4,2` is bitonic (rising until 7, then falling until the end; `99,4,8,16` is as well (falling until 4, then rising until the end).

**The task is to test, whether a sequence is bitonic** (without being monotonic), with your code being as short as possible in your language of choice.

**Input**: A list of positive integer numbers without duplicates in a form that suits your language.

**Output**: [Truthy/falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19205/72726)

**Test data**:

```
True:
1,3,5,7,6,4,2
99,4,8,16
100000,10000,1000,100,10,1,11,111,1111,11111,111111
2,1,3,4,5,6

False:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2,1
1,4,7,6,2,3,5
99,88,66,77,55,44,33,22,11
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
```

Comment: [Related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199055/53748).

Comment: How is `99,4,8,16` bitonic? which for is less than both 99 and 8?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi It goes down from 99 to 4, then up from 4 over 8 to 16. Two monotonic sequences form one bitonic sequence.

Comment: In research papers, such sequences or functions are usually called [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function)

Comment: Are there any guarantees about the length of the input?

Comment: @chunes I guarantee it's finite. (-; If the language you choose has a problem with arrays > 255 elements or numbers > 65535 or the like, I don't want to exclude it. As long as it doesn't destroy the spirit of the challenge (like having only three elements), I don't have a problem with some limits. And you can assume there will be no empty lists.

Comment: "without being monotonic": I suggest removing this part, because a falsy test case can be tritonic, tetratonic, pentatonic...

Comment: @Joao-3 Depending on the definition, some may consider a monotonic sequence being a special case of a bitonic sequence, so I want to explicitly say, that only *real* bitonic sequences count with two arms count

Comment: @Philippos Ok then :)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 10 bytes

```
eL2<gr<pac
```

*(Doesn't work on ato since ato is slightly out of date)*

### Explanation

- `pac` gets the contour of a list, i.e. the comparisons between consecutive elements
- `gr` group them into sections of equal elements.
- `eL2` check if there are exactly two groups

### Reflection

A couple of thoughts here

- I think there might be use in having a function which counts the number of groups. Although I don't think it would help this particular answer.
- `pWK` gets all partitions where each part satisfies a predicate. A version of this could be `ay eL2<pWK(lq<pac)`, which is much longer although there are a bunch of ways to improve this approach.

  - `lq<pac` determines if a list is monotonic, that is useful.  We already have functions for the specific monotonicities, this would be a nice addtion.
  - Versions of a lot of the partitioning functions that are specific to partition into two parts would be useful, since that is the most basic non-trivial type of partition. A version of `pWK` which is specific to size 2 would change this from `ay eL2`, checking if there is something of size 2, to `ø`, checking if the result is null.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
IṠITL’
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of different integers and yields `0` (falsey) if it is bitonic or a non-zero integer (truthy) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4c4FniE@jxpm/v//P9pSx1THSMdCx9AoFgA)** Or ee the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##PY87CsJAEIZ7T2Er/IWTZB@pBBsJiJVdSKNYRIJp0tils7dSUPAaqcWDJBdZZ7JJlp2feXwzO3s@FcXVuaRtPsl@29VP97u3zQNd/dqV1fyQV@UlP3b1mxPrKfjeVouNc2kaQCHMZkhDdgJxCOIaaEQ@EcfsWZDuq0s5oElF2EAgub15GZSkLYCMjXiwn4JgDGEkIc8pToRcIE9E/Q7CqWELa6GZN1CMMssw0wMeM2oZNtyofQuNP/MrZLPsDw).

#### How?

The count of direction changes must be exactly one, so count them and subtract one to give `0` iff the input is bitonic.

```
IṠITL’ - Link: list, A       e.g. [5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2]
I      - forward differences      [ -1,-1, 3, 1,-5]
 Ṡ     - signs                    [ -1,-1, 1, 1,-1]
  I    - forward differences      [   0, 2, 0,-2]
   T   - truthy indices           [      2,    4]
    L  - length                   2
     ’ - decrement                1 (truthy: not bitonic)
```

Comment: Golfing languages are just unbeatable. I swear, Jelly is so often under 10 bytes

Comment: @Hakaishin Please don't let golfing languages dissuade you, just try to make code as short as you can in the language of your choice and have some fun with it. (We generally don't give the green tick here anymore, because of the vast language differences).

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 31 bytes

```r
\(x,`?`=diff)sum(!!?sign(?x))-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBNasMwEIX3OkXilQTPpeP4R4YmvogXCVQKBtcYywEXcpNu3ELP0XP0MqUzUVsqNG-kp29mQC-v0_rm9--X2af2o9ULjs1x_9h5b8LlSW-3TejOg24WY1KK1OeXcstDukkIOxSoUCJHpuqakwWViu5lgf5UhAMEkn2LKD9KKoN0y7kf1yP7PaNS0r_g245d4rf8NlGIQmZai5KxCgVDTDHGnIA1Q5axiku4RXI9hHkKY9_NOmnbITHXg-u1-W9DzP40jv2zPoW7bpjd2U1GhWi5BRtv4i-sa8zf)

A function taking a vector of integers and returning falsy for bitonic and truthy for non-bitonic. Takes some inspiration from @JonathanAllan’s Jelly answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to att.

```apl
1=1⊥2≠/2>/⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NCsIwEIX3nuItE7DWSZsmXehFxEWpVoSCQrrxAoJdeQQRBM/hUXKROIk/IfPCZL68R5pjn21OTX/YZW3fOLdvQ@j8@UoL8uND@cstV8vcj/cQhq0bHHgmCAU0DCqUUFLUNZ8WVElB87hAf43CBQLFneojXyUpFKJhyZbRAerXwEgRQzS3BV9TnJYpNzI6JVuLikkDzRhzDDKZ0Joxy6DhR@wiJ5P0hemKZnrdvZ6pewM)

```apl
1=1⊥2≠/2>/⊢­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
       2>/⊢  ⍝ ‎⁡compare successive terms with > (direction of deltas)
    2≠/      ⍝ ‎⁢compare successive terms with ≠ (changes in direction)
  1⊥         ⍝ ‎⁣sum (# of changes in direction)
1=           ⍝ ‎⁤equal to 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: `+/` -> `1⊥` and you can remove the parens

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
IṠŒgL=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49CsJAEIX7PUVI/QRnk81uCNoL1oIHEEFyAbtgY2@t4AEsbYJgEzxIcpH1TfxZZt7szzdvdrep632Mi769vk7b5czGvn1WQ3NOJvNkaC5VdzT9474aDrfuSFnHmKapIIODR4Ec1pQlS4AURqa6IH9VYUIgGmN@5KtiLNQtpx/7YX97eKP@jqeMt8K3fJyohNOZIaAg5uEIkSJGTsGSUCDm2UILfvgN)

### Explanation

```
I       | Increments
 Ṡ      | Signs
  Œg    | Group consecutive equal values
    L=2 | Length is equal to two?
```

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 80 bytes

```
=regexmatch(join(,sort((D1:Y1<E1:1)+2*(D1:Y1>E1:1)*(E1:1>0))),"^(1+2+|2+1+)0*$")
```

Put the number sequence in cells `D1:Z1` and the formula in cell `A1`.

Simple [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) and string matching. Makes just one pass through the array. The `sort()` does not actually sort anything — its purpose is to enable array processing.

Expects that the last number is in or before column `Z`. If you need more columns, replace `:1` with `:Z1` (3 bytes) and insert columns before `Y` as necessary.

[image: bitonic]

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->a,*l{l.chunk{|x|a<=>a=x}.count==2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5RC4IwFIXf@xU9x0nadG5C84@EDyZIkFhEgqH@9nVuM8fuYffufGd7DddPaH04ljUO3dQlzW3o79M8zvXZl7Ufl6R5DP3be72E5769KKQwsMiRQVc7GRUFzw4qj606yYLaVIQFBSX7V1FWVRHUkPCM8UyKUdD/CWw0ycuGo5RXK6fYyli8ZvuSc8hJWRja6SdAYkMK2h0BS5iJVfgC)

Probably the same idea as @JonathanAllan’s Jelly answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

This is implementation-dependent, as it assumes that the `sort()` algorithm compares the items by pairs from left to right, at least while \$x\ge0\$ (after which it no longer matters because we already know that the sequence is not bitonic anyway).

Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
a=>a.sort(s=(a,b)=>x-=s!=(s=a>b),x=2)|!x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LDoIwEEX3/gWsaDIQW96LsvQL3CGLgvgKoYaiwcR/r1N8RGObzk3aO3Nm5iSuQjXD8Tz6vdy2ese14IUIlBxGT3FPQE14MflcORzfoqgJTJyRuzPpRvZKdm3Qyb3nluvhMh5ulUsW3/87r6QQQgwpJBABq8ifn@doZEATi0eX5gD9qBEMoEDNneMpL6UWCgMzQ4RTzD1@bHfTlyvRKfvk7F0HqYVrdorRDzHP1peiZ3IMJbZvnmWQIDyFGEFIQhSy7LAcQRmiUsQmM1A/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 43 bytes

```perl
s/\d+ ?/$&>$'||B/ge;chop;$_=/^(B+1+|1+B+)$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDoIwEEDRfU8xiwY1ExwGaJEQNeneGxhdKFETQhtx2bM7jrv/XxrfkxNZ6HxHOJItDnaVc6DHONyeMQ32uqfLOiBjZgy4sSTC0ICDDjy0UBuGWr9V8dCZvzq9RpVN32vugP03ps8rzouUJ7etuJIyTT8)

Comment: [https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZFW8FeX0XNTkW9psZJPz3VWiXeVj9Ow0nbULvGUNtJW1NPRf//f0MFYwVTBXMFMwUTBSMuQwUjIN8EKGKmYM4FEjUF8oyBooZclpZApoWCodm//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULcgA Try it online!] 39 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
!L=sum((~=diff)(~L.>0).^2)==1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NqsIwEIX3eYq4MoFDcWp/F3Ev@AwXCm0hEmNpK7jy1euJ3nuHmTP5@ebM9RF8J89t213c8rgZ83K9H0drXpfsdLDZT26dk228z9prH/U8dH3wcViMVZoRtNNTNy9DZs5xxTIFvxqPPfb2C0yzj2uIJrjTLlg1xH4THFGiRoUCuWpbtgZSKTmkgPxrEhYEkvJTX/lVUTmSW0E/ziP/O6NWyb/k7chX4V/x2ZiIMu1sGlTEapSESBEjl8CWUEOs5ggt3g)

based on multiple other answers

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ü.SÔg<
```

Outputs an 05AB1E truthy/falsey value, so `1` if truthy and `0` or a positive integer if falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8B694MNT0m3@/4821DHWMdUx1zHTMdExigUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PY5BCsIwEEWvErJS@IhpmyYFoRtv4LJ0UaFqQRBsFbpw6wHEW3gFd72JF4l/rBoyn5nJmz85tNW6qcO5z7V6XW9K530YnrPVcN8uwjJvtJp0x1O366d6eLDYVPu2ZnFBKAqDGBYOKRJEJYosY@JhUuZmLgfmryIMGBi5nxjlq4ZTEcQzoSs9FBdEvxKOz7LKso7ZF9wwl55QdvyA90gJO1iCJImSHeGMoCfqOEajsnwD).

**Explanation:**

```python
ü       # For each overlapping pair of the (implicit) input-list:
 .S     #  Compare them: 1 if a>b; 0 if a==b; -1 if a<b
   Ô    # Connected uniquify this list
    g   # Pop and push the length
     <  # Decrease it by 1
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
│mσ│┘Σ┴
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PY27EcIwEERzatmAk/WtxeOABBzYQ0IF0IICclqgDuhBjYg9yVij27mV3u2tp9t8uS7nWku@r98HteTn51Xyu9ZRMMAhwMPCTIcxJTYR4tnLUQ9kVxUWBKK3VZdNhVMGmmmZ2jJg/g6BXjc5@oHv0v5t266U6/tjhCcc4AiSJEq2w4lgJBo4xqDpBw)

**Explanation:**

```python
│        # Get the forward differences of the (implicit) input-list
 m       # Map over each integer:
  σ      #  Get its sign
   │     # Get the forward differences of this list again
    ┘    # Check for each that they're NOT equal to 0
     Σ   # Sum the amount of non-zero values together
      ┴  # Check whether this is equal to 1
         # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 15 bytes

Prompts for input.

```
1=+/2=|2-/×2-/⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwEEX3cxV/qZM2TbroAQTFM5RKRSgouBJcqytxIx7Im/Qi8SdVQ@bzZ@bNTHsYss2pHfbbrBva43HXhfH@XC3Hy6MQusWaTmW8XfugzSw3zdlk@ftFYTewLqEXRQELhwoljPRS1zQeWtHrPD7oX6MwoND4U0zyVeWUQdxZcmvaAfPL4JjHS5Z5wbqmfpmuR8pO971HRdjBEiRJlOwE1wQ9UccxLpIP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 29 bytes

```
($_ Z-.skip)>>.sign.squish==2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY5LTsMwEIb3OcXIKlUjTS3sxokjSC7Bjg3qgoDVB22cLCrESdhkAQs23ICD5Db9pwEsz_j1zTd-_2jXm3742p1o3lBFr5991yz9z2L2QPdLHTfhkNa1juFpr-OxD_G5quzEjLdvNxTXJ9J3XaubXbdQV85GlTIpqmr4IEkVNS8tbcP-MYrnsA3gWKWTYxi_Da_YccE5Z2yTssTi2eSJuZbB5j9LQrBhI_MSU_rNJrEstgw-1LP923ORiN_htMKtwVt26SiEk57ecw6sYAcIFDBwApaAPLACJVBM3z4D)

Zip-subtract the sequence with itself-skipped, i.e., take the differences and further take the sign of those differences. Lastly "squish" the signs, which squeezes consecutive duplicates into one, i.e., uniq of UNIX; if we have 2 unique signs at the end, sequence is bitonic.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `0` for `true` or a non-zero integer for `false`.

```
äÎòÎÊÍ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5M7yzsrN&input=W1sxLDMsNSw3LDYsNCwyXSxbOTksNCw4LDE2XSxbMTAwMDAwLDEwMDAwLDEwMDAsMTAwLDEwLDEsMTEsMTExLDExMTEsMTExMTEsMTExMTExXSxbMiwxLDMsNCw1LDZdLCBbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsN10sWzcsNiw1LDQsMywyLDFdLFsxLDQsNyw2LDIsMyw1XSxbOTksODgsNjYsNzcsNTUsNDQsMzMsMjIsMTFdLFsxLDksMiw4LDMsNyw0LDYsNV1dLW1S)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 62 bytes

```c
i;f(*l,z){i=*l=*l>l[1];return--z-1?f(l+1,z)+(i%2-*l&&++i):-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRasIwFIbv@xRBUBp7Spe0TVKL292eYHdOhrh2BLJu1Hqj@OzdqdY6ok1IDgQO3///J9mGW7OpvtpW56U/N3CgR72cG9zPZsXWeV00@7oKw0PIXkrfBAw7Al9PeTg3s1kQaLoIWX5qvze68unRi6K3el8sPF01pCl2zQcjq/XySBjEkIIEAQlwcsq93xpbSn8y/XyvJlD6124gO30ofkq/v9Oov2M7pTT3bmh@QZMsQ6gCJsa5nFhgfg8euHHPZU/dAjbUruABBqzb53MpfWXjDmLbQexwkPQOOHRzS3ByjmyJTU4eDC2KXjdm9/9h0mtK4FcNkKMiqS2SOuyLHt09d4roGCXYKFrYaOFAy8F1cv5Nnfd0FC1ttHSg1e07KQUCpyEhRfvoHwNggvEIytZRDp1siJChfYUBJIYRjhiZjc8evPCp/QM)

Return false if bitonic , true otherwise

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 14 bytes

```
=1/+≡/≠◫2≡/>◫2
```

Gets windows, compares, gets windows, counts changes in comparisons and checks if the number of changes is exactly 1.

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgPTEvK-KJoS_iiaDil6sy4omhLz7il6syCgojIFRydXRoeQpGIDFfM181XzdfNl80XzIKRiA5OV80XzhfMTYKRiAxMDAwMDBfMTAwMDBfMTAwMF8xMDBfMTBfMV8xMV8xMTFfMTExMV8xMTExMV8xMTExMTEKRiAyXzFfM180XzVfNgoKIyBGYWxzeQpGICsx4oehNyAgIyAxXzJfM180XzVfNl83CkYg4oeMKzHih6E3ICMgN182XzVfNF8zXzJfMQpGIDFfNF83XzZfMl8zXzUKRiDih4zDlzExKzHih6E5ICMgOTlfODhfNzdfNjZfNTVfNDRfMzNfMjJfMTEK)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 39 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(?<=(1+)),1\1
;
1

^,+;+$|^;+,+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY29DsIwDIR3P0eQUnIDbpsmUUGMvERVgQQDC0PFyLuHc/mJ7IvjfD4vt@f9cakbfzrX6RrEbcUf9wevoWmgk8ooKjIjjMG95jEguFoVHSISBvRopRReGTqI7uxA/2rChEIt1vzIV1VamFtPP86j/dVIYv6Rr45d5V@/bjQi2s6cMRBLiIRIESNnYCGUiSWO0OIN) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of @NickKennedy's Jelly answer.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the integers to unary.

```
(?<=(1+)),1\1
;
```

Replace the comma with a semicolon for all ascending pairs. (The lookbehind both allows the "matches" to overlap and being atomic finds the start of the unary value without needing a word boundary.)

```
1
```

Delete any remaining `1`s.

```
^,+;+$|^;+,+$
```

Check whether the sequence is bitonic.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
≔ＥΦθκ›ι§θκθ⁼№θ§θ⁰⌕θ¬§θ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7FAwy0zpyS1SKNQRyFbU0fBvSg1EcTN1FFwLPHMS0mtgMhoAuUKNa25Aooy80o0XAtLE3OKNZzzS4GcQhSlBiCVbpl5KSCOX36JBqocCFj//x8dbahjrGOqY65jpmOiYxQb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ＥΦθκ›ι§θκθ
```

Create a list of `1`s and `0`s corresponding to whether the overlapping pairs of integers are ascending or descending.

```
⁼№θ§θ⁰⌕θ¬§θ⁰
```

Check that the count of occurrences of the first element is also the start of the second run of identical elements; if there is only one run then there is no start of the second run while if there are more than two runs then there are too many of the first element to fit before the second run.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 84 bytes

```clj
#(=(sort(mapcat set(partition-by +(for[i(map -(rest %)%)](Long/signum i)))))'(-1 1))
```

Annoyingly `partition-all` is a long function name, and the static function call `Long/signum` (which outputs -1, 0 or 1) cannot be directly composed with `-` using `comp`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvRDoIwDEXf@YomhtjFEh2iPvkH/gHZA@JmZmAj23jw6ycbxLb3pOnt7Qf7mZ2MEV9SgYId3tFbF3Dspr4L4GXAqXNBB21N9fzCAZV1rU4@VOikD1Cykgl8WPM@ev028wiapdpjxYEvS1Hg5LQJg4GcU9AWAC0/pSL@Z8Ii4sTTZK3YyEXO0ZkudKMrNVSvF1h685rs1OlHFIKxGH8)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 12 chars

```
1=≢⍸∼2=/2</⎕
```

This above it seems ok for all test
how to use it:

```
  1=≢⍸∼2=/2</⎕ 
⎕:
  1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5
0
```

test but the char "∼" in Tio is not the same char of the answer.

https://tio.run/##PY09DsIwDIX3nOWh4rT5qUQPgATiDJVQWSrBysIIZQCxcAFOwXlykfCSAFH89Gx/tvvDONse@3G/i@H@XK/C@VEruuWGTlSYLkOULlxf4fY@6a7Si4rdyHoclKCGgYNFA60G1bY0HmLpZZ4e5K9JGBBI@jmKfFU4pZF2Ntyad0D/Mjjm6ZJhXrMuud/k64ky5b73sIQdDEGSRMkWuCXoiTqOcdEH

Comment: Do you have an explanation and a link how to test it?

Comment: the explenation is that in each sequence increase and after decrease or viceversa there is one and only one element that has in one side the increase and other side the decrease or viceversa

Comment: You can drop the `~` and replace the second equals with not equals

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 42 bytes

```
f(L)=d(d(L))^2.total-1
d(L)=sgn(L[2...]-L)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jds74gswcp)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fx8hl8ekfc)

Returns `0` if bitonic or a non-zero integer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 143 bytes

Minimal version:

```
func b(_ a:[Int])->Bool{var c=[Int]();for i in 0..<a.count-1{let s=(a[i+1]-a[i]).signum();if s != 0 && s != c.last{c+=[s]}};return c.count==2}
```

Verbose version:

```
func bitonic3(_ array: [Int]) -> Bool {
    let a = array
    var changes: [Int] = []
    var reducedChanges: [Int] = []

    for i in 0 ..< a.count - 1 {
        let sign = (a[i+1] - a[i]).signum()
        if sign != 0 {
            changes.append(sign)
        }
    }

    for i in 0 ..< changes.count {
        let value = changes[i]
        if reducedChanges.last != value {
            reducedChanges.append(value)
        }
    }
    
    if reducedChanges.count != 2 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
∆±ĉđ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY8xDsIwDEV3ToEy_0q4bZr0LFWHgsqCCkPLFRCMzCwdQAKJhRsg1EuwchJ-kkIUf9nO87dyuq7r1aapuupeqKhRmKqoVmV_2XbLyN4--93rMRyG47mdL9qx27-fhSCBhkGGFHE5KfKciYVkzGXmDuSvThgQiLs-gowqnIrhPFO6eg_EvwqGtdukWSfsi39P_XZH6bDfWmSEDTRBkkTJBjgnaIkajtGoDB_5Ag)

```
∆±ĉđ
∆       Delta; differences between consecutive elements
 ±      Sign
  ĉ     Split into chunks of identical elements
   đ    Unpair; check if length is 2
```